# Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни

Tags: обсуждение, faq, модерация, правки, приветствия

Исходное обсуждение на Meta.StackOverflow.com:

[**Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

При обсуждении вопроса как поступать с текстом, напрямую не относящимся к обсуждению, на Stack Overflow на английском пришли к консенсусу: никакого избыточного текста в вопросах быть не должно. При редактировании постов следует удалять избыточный текст. Если привилегии редактирования без проверки ещё нет, то вычисткой *исключительно* избыточного текста (без прочих исправлений) лучше не заниматься.

Такое мнение было высказано ромбовым модератором, и с ним согласилось абсолютное большинство голосовавших (+161/−10). Все ответы, высказывающиеся за избыточный текст, были сурово заминусованы сообществом (от +18/−19 до +2/−11).

Однако на Stack Overflow на русском я встретился с сопротивлением отдельных пользователей, которые восстанавливают приветствия и прочие фразы вежливости.

Какова официальная политика Stack Overflow на русском? Отличается ли она от политики англоязычного Stack Overflow?

**Об автоматизации проверки сообщений на содержание fluff:** [Нужна ли автоматическая резка приветствий?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/465/181472)

Comment: Всем, привет! Как дела?

Comment: Здороваться на стэковерфлоу, как оказалось - нельзя!
С новым годом, тоже!
Всё это издержки буржуйской интеллигенции, сопли аристократии, товарищи!
Общаться надо лишь кодом! И только кодом!

Comment: Это получается, что http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439780/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-ruby-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B отсюда тоже надо вступление удалить?

Comment: @MAXOPKA Сложности поиска нужных идентификаторов в гугле — это тоже часть проблемы, можно оставить.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Сайты Stack Exchange существуют для организации информации.

Приветствия, подписи и мольбы о помощи не добавляют и бита полезной информации. Кто-то сказал "привет", кто-то сказал "здравствуйте, друзья", кто-то — "хай, чуваки, как чо?" Скажите, вы будете полагаться на приветствия или на содержание поста, которое следует за ним?

Лирические отступления и истории из жизни ещё хуже — они служат препятствием к быстрому и эффективному получению информации. И особенно отвратительно, когда они вперемешку с основным содержанием. Время в современном мире бесценно, и каждой историей вы отодвигаете тысячи посетителей от впитывания полезной информации. Если уж очень хочется описать ситуацию — перенестие её аккуратно в посткриптум в конец поста, чтобы оно никому не мешало.

Что касается выражения благодарности, то существует аж три функции: поставить плюс вопросу, ответу или комментарию; принять ответ как верный; наградить ответ через "конкурс". На всех сайтах Stack Exchange традиционно удаляются комментарии "спасибо", и даже существует "защита" популярных вопросов от новичков, которые любят постить подобные сообщения. Что уж говорить, если во многих форумных движках появляются кнопки "+1" и похожие, чтобы не засорять форум сообщениями про то, что кто-то с чем-то согласен, но ничего своего сказать не может.

Comment: Ещё способ выражения благодарности: конкурс (тема: "Наградить существующий ответ").

Comment: вопросы задают и пишут ответы на них люди, а не роботы. Человеческое общение почти что требует добавления не несущей полезной нагрузки информации (small talk). Согласен, что после принятия ответа (когда решение уже найдено), последующие посетители мало от приветствий выиграют, поэтому их можно удалить, чтобы сигнал/шум повысить, если вы правкой по какой-то ещё причине занимаетесь или если вопрос очень популярен (чтобы список активных вопросов не засорять просто так правками, которые заметных улучшений не вносят).

Answer (score 40):

Угу, я из этих "отдельных" юзеров.
Вежливость нужна, мы приличное общество в конце-концов!
Я сам выпиливаю фразочки типа "Я новичок, помогите!" - это бессмысленно.
Так же не нужно писать ответами "Спасибо!" и пр., для этого карма есть.
Но поздороватся как-то... по-человечьи, да и не сильно мешает, зато читающему приятно. Как в жизни, короче.
Про остальное ("Подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни") согласен (хотя если, например, короткая история из жизни пояснит ситуацию, то почему нет?).

Comment: Соглашусь. Хоть проект и является адаптацией StackOverflow для русскоговорящих пользователей - не следует передирать все правила и принципы с англоязычного проекта.

Comment: Тем не менее это есть в "модели" и лично мне непонятно приветствие "Добрый вечер" когда сейчас день или ночь. Зачем этот информационный мусор? Мне кажется это стало неким жаргоном. Почитайте письма того времени когда люди писали _настоящие_ письма. Там никогда не было "Доброго времени суток". Это если говорить о русском языке. А если на язык наплевать, так мы и до "олбанского" дойдем.

Comment: @tutankhamun, Добрый вечер!
Это высказывание относится к приветствию (не знаю откуда пошло указание времени суток, возможно показать собеседнику когда он пишет...). Я никак не пойму что плохого в приветствии? ОК, писать на пять строчек со всеми титулами и словами "Ваше высокопревосходительство" и т.п. не нужно, но элементарно поздороваться или пожелать приятного дня можно же!

Comment: @TheDoctor Здравствуйте! В чате отлично подойдет и "добрый вечер" поскольку идет общение в реальном времени. В письмах (даже в электронных), на мой взгляд, это уже глупость. Есть вполне подходящие слова "здравствуй(те)" или "привет" (в зависимости от уровня знакомства с собеседником). Тут же совершенно практическая цель - собрать в одном месте решения проблем, а не личное общение.

Comment: @tutankhamun, Поздороваться - это уже личное общение? Сильно...
Я не знаю какой язык для Вас родной, но в русском (впрочем, в остальных похожая ситуация) есть куча слов приветствия: "Привет", "Здравствуй", "Добрый день", даже "Здорово, лошара!" (последнее для закадычных друзей :)). Всё это одной группы, просто ранжируется по ситуации. Так что без разницы - Добрый день или Привет - это одна фигня: приветствие, некое вступление, без "с места в карьер".

Comment: @TheDoctor Что-то мы тут прямо теологический спор затеяли :) Вот по поводу "Здорово, лошара!" я как раз и написал что если позволять всё, то дойдем и, например, до олбанского. Вы поймите - я не против приветствия в принципе. Просто есть правила и их следует соблюдать. Особенно если это совсем не сложно.

Comment: @tutankhamun, Угу, люблю пофилософствовать :)
А по поводу последней фразы я специально в скобках написал - только для закадычных друзей и, разумеется, оно не подходит для this site.

Comment: "Угу" - на стэкоферфлоу нельзя!
"Короче" тоже нельзя!

Answer (score 28):

Абсолютно согласен с ответом [@Discord](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176051). Как дополнение, Stack Overflow на русском придерживается стандартной модели - сайт направлен на кристаллизацию знаний. **Все элементы сообщения не влияющие на качество и информативность сообщения *могут* быть опущены.**

Русский язык достаточно выразительный, чтобы показать уважение к коллегам не прибегая к не информативным словам. Например, можно использовать "вы" вместо "ты", или излагать вопрос/ответ без использования местоимений вообще.

Comment: Думаю, этот вопрос достоин метки FAQ.

Comment: Атмосфера вежливости и доброжелательности также имеет значение. Разные аудитории у вопроса есть. Сухая математическая формулировка может быть не лучшей, для привлечения внимания людей способных ответить на вопрос: чтобы лучший результат получить, процесс может иметь значение. Из популярных вопросов, когда основная аудитория уже это посетители из поисковика, а не активные участники, можно тогда выпиливать неинформативные части. Иначе поощрять тривиальные правки вопросов не стоит (если новых вопросов мало, лучше старые вопросы поднимать, которые возможно недостаточно внимания получили).

Comment: Этимологически "вы" и "враг" - однокоренные слова. Да, 60% населения об этом и не ведают, но остальные могут воспринимать весьма остро.

Answer (score 16):

Процитирую пару абзацев от [Eric Steven Raymond](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html), касающиеся этого вопроса.

> #### Публичное самоунижение не заменяет выполнение домашних заданий
>
> Некоторые, уяснив, что не надо вести себя грубо или надменно, вымогая ответ, выбирают противоположную крайность - самоунижение. "Я знаю, я начинающий, неудачник и полный чайник, но...". Это отвлекает от сути и не имеет смысла. Особенно в сочетании с неопределенностью в описании фактической проблемы.
>
> Не тратьте свое время, и наше, уповая на жалость. Представьте лучше факты и свой вопрос как можно яснее. Так вы заявите о себе гораздо лучше, чем путем самоунижения.
>
> #### Избегайте бессмысленных просьб
>
> Не поддавайтесь соблазну завершить свой запрос бессмысленными вопросами вида: "Не поможет ли мне кто-нибудь?" или "Есть ли вообще ответ?" Во-первых, если вы хоть сколько-нибудь компетентно описали свою проблему, подобные дополнительные вопросы, как минимум, излишни. Во-вторых, поскольку они излишни, <s>хакерам</s> сообществу StackOverflow они кажутся надоедливыми — и в ответ их так и подбивает написать логически безукоризненную отписку типа: "Да, помочь вам можно" или "Нет, вам уже ничем не поможешь".
>
> В общем случае, вопросы с ответами да-нет лучше не задавать, если только вы не хотите получить ответ да-или-нет.

Comment: Для случая "да/нет" я бы не давал таких рекомендаций. Понимаю, во многих случаях, это требует тривиального ответа и не менее тривиального доказательства. Термин "во многих" завораживает))) А вот представьте вариант. Вопрос: "верно ли, что для всякого натурального числа n между n^2 и (n + 1)^2 всегда найдётся простое число?" и на него опубликовали ответ "да", да еще и с доказательством ... Была  бы просто "бобма". Но вам она не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Из того, как задан вопрос, можно принять решение, стоит ли вообще на него пытаться отвечать. Поэтому я за то, чтобы приветствия и подобные штуки оставались в сообщении.

Answer (score 0):

Подобного рода фразы могут иметь разную основу: эпатажа, покрасоваться, приукрасить сообщение. Но иногда это выражение чувств человека, его настроения. Не только технически сухо спросить но и выразить свои эмоции, например хорошее настроение.

Если это урезать, то сайт станет более сухим и чёрствым.

У многих технарей и так проблемы есть с выражением чувств, так зачем это ещё усугублять и усиливать.

Понятное дело что SO это сайт по техническим вопросам и ответам, но чуть-чуть просто общения не помешает а наоборот поможет сайту быть более живым. Например под новый год некоторые участники поздравляли друг-друга с новым годом, разве не может этому быть место на SO. Мы же не только программисты но и люди в первую очередь.

Если говорить конкретно про приветствия например, то согласен что для сообщений с большим количеством просмотров это было бы лишнем и можно убирать. Но вводить урезаловку на обычное и нормальное человеческое общение (там где оно уместно и в тему) смысла не вижу. Я не говорю что всё это обязательно должно быть на сайте, но думаю что этот вопрос не решается шаблонным правилом, а зависит от каждой конкретной ситуации.

Answer (score -4):

Предлагаю делать подобные правки только для вопросов, которые собирают больше какого-то числа просмотров, например 100.
Подавляющее же большинство вопросов - единоразовые, обычно в них заходят несколько десятков раз, пока они висят в топе неотвеченными. Поискового трафика нет, т.к. вопрос либо связан с ошибкой в конкретном коде, либо с непониманием автором, что он вообще накопипастил, либо с неумением гуглить.
Например по тегу javascript ежедневно задается один и тот же по сути вопрос про замыкания в разных вариациях ([сегодня например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486832/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-javascript), или [вчера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486204/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-javascript), как раз с [правкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/486204/revisions) ). В этот вопрос вряд-ли кто-нибудь когда нибудь попадет из какого-либо поиска. 
В подобных вопросах поведение модераторов заставляет вспомнить выражение "синдром вахтера". Человек пытается быть вежливым, а его за это попрекают правилами.

Answer (score -7):

Предлагаю универсальный способ!

Нужно заменить все приветствия с временами суток - добрыми, нейтральными, злыми. А так же слезувыбивающие истории, новеллы, просьбы, мольбы и заклинания, повествования о жизни, сметри, трудностях и радостях ... впрочем как и моззговыносящих нейтральностях ....универсальной фразой "Yo!"

**Сами посудите, универсальная фраза "Yo!":**

- количество символом меньше "пи" и больше "e", это впечатляет, немного туповато, но действенно!!! ... Люто математикой веет, Перельман тихо плачет;
- "три", хорошая цифра, я бы сказал пролетарская, знак пролетарского качества, это почти пять! Только немножко минус два;
- твердый знак какбэ подчеркивает глубину, китайственность внутреннего стиля писателя, возможно прозаика. Хм, а возможно и нет. Главное, что не японец, главное, что не сеппуку!

Голосуйте за "Yo!". Необходимые условия я озвучил, достаточные условия - прошу платно!