# Запрет редактирования постов

Tags: предложение, модерация, правки

С недавнего времени начал замечать что мои посты с фанатичностью виталины (кто пришел с хешкода поймут о чем я) редактирует пользователь **Athari**. В частности удаляет приветствие из сообщения (я конечно все понимаю, менталитет у всех разный, но давайте будем соблюдать хоть какие то рамки приличия).

Есть ли возможность запретить конкретному пользователю редактировать мои посты? И если такой возможности нету - будет ли она добавлена в будущем?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7)

Comment: Ну все в принципе понятно. Закрытие "неугодного" вопроса. Другого и не ожидал.

Comment: А как вы предлагаете отмечать повторяющиеся проблемы/вопросы?

Comment: Я предлагаю не "забивать" на проблемы, а попытаться найти компромисс. И если уж на том пошло, цитата: "Сообщество единогласно согласилось в том, что излишнюю доброжелательность можно опускать." - не верна. Часть сообщества против. Ни о каком единогласии не может быть и речи. И да, вопросы - не дубликаты по сути. Вопросы заданы с разных сторон (стороны, которая любит редактировать чужие сообщения, удалять неугодные комментарии и т.д. и стороны - которой не нравится когда в их посты лезет неизвестно кто, что-то изменяет, да и в добавок удаляет комментарии).

Comment: Мне кажется, что вопросы очень похожи. Если отбросить повествование, то суть проблемы - "Мне не нравится, что из моих постов удаляют приветствия и т.п.". Позиция SO отражена в упомянутом по ссылке вопросе. И как видно ниже, все ответы идут именно на этот вопрос.

Comment: @Krom Stern, позиция всего RU SO? Позиция не единогласна - это раз. Два - в данной теме более детально все разобрано. Три - в предыдущей теме неясна конечная позиция, просто 2 ответа за, и один - против. Нет ни опроса пользователей, ни конечного решения администрации и т.д. Помоему глупо закрывать эту тему, если ответ на предыдущую - расплывчат.

Comment: Если темы совпадают, то следует использовать предыдущую для продолжения обсуждения или голосования за ответы, а не создавать дубликат. Если же этот вопрос не дубликат, то стоит отредактировать его и сделать более точно сформулированым.

Comment: Вы читайте то что я пишу? Все есть в комментариях выше.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23683/discussion-between-krom-stern-and-z668).

Comment: @z668: Насколько я понимаю, политика насчёт приветствий — это фишка именно самого en.SO. По поводу нужности или ненужности приветствий, и правда, не стоит слепо перенимать правила en.SO, я лично не против приветствий.

Comment: @z668: По поводу редактирования чужих в общем-то нормальных сообщений: конечно, гораздо проще отредактировать хорошее сообщение, убрав приветствие, чем исправить реально плохое сообщение. Многие тянутся за простой работой: для того, чтобы реально улучшить реально плохое сообщение, требуется серьёзная работа, а сообщение с приветствием — лёгкая добыча. Постарайтесь относиться к этому философски. :-\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересная тема, кстати, я сам удаляю приветствия при редактировании, чисто на автомате, подражая большому SO. Но на мой взгляд, в этом нет никакой нужды. Они не являются мусором, т.е. приветствие это настолько малая часть вопроса, что помешать она точно не может.

А раз есть люди, которых это обижает (они хотят, чтобы их вопрос содержал приветствие), то я предлагаю подходить к этому вопросу мягче. Почему бы не оставлять приветствия, на самом деле? Лично я больше не буду их удалять.

Answer (score 8):

Добрый вечер!

В целом приветствия и, особенно, предыстории вида "я только недавно начал изучать php" тут не приветствуются. Они шумят. Они не приносят пользы (кроме создания теплой ламповой атмосферы).

Ну и к тому же они достаточно странно выглядят когда пишешь "добрый день" одному и тому же человеку несколько раз за пару часов. Плюсы и минусы удаления чужих приветствий разобраны [на английской мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), не знаю, стоит ли подробно переводить их в качестве аргументов в этом обсуждении.

IMO, Не стоит редактировать посты *только* ради удаления приветствия. Но вполне нормально убить при любых других изменениях в тексте вопроса.

Спасибо за уделенное внимание.

С уважением,

Павел.

P.S. если коротко - поговорите с @Athari в чате, думаю он вполне вас поймет и не будет трогать ваши сообщения. Любые существующие правки можно откатить в один клик - у вас достаточно репутации.

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что правки к *своему* посту (о чём речь) можно откатить вне зависимости от репутации.

Comment: @Yes ...но это не значит, что их нужно откатывать. :)

Comment: @Athari, для начала не нужно лезть в чужие вопросы. У вас есть свои вопросы\ответы, вот в них и копайтесь.

Comment: @PashaPash, по поводу постскриптума вашего ответа. Почему я должен просить кого то не трогать мои сообщения? Я понимаю если бы правки были полезными, например исправлена техническая ошибка, дополнено\исправлено описание проблемы для лучшего восприятия и т.д. Вам например понравится если ваши посты редактируют? Приведу еще один пример, последнее время некоторые интернет провайдеры в трафик стали пихать рекламу\технические сообщения и т.д. Мне это не нравится, вам думаю тоже не понравится.

Comment: @z668 Вам уже всё объяснили про "лезть в чужие вопросы". Что вам ещё не понятно? Последнее время я исправлял неправильные метки, заодно исправлял остальные недостатки. Если у вас есть примеры, когда качество постов пострадало, приведите их.

Comment: @z668 редактирование чужих постов - это то, что отличает SO от других сайтов. Считайте, что запостив тут текст, вы отдатете его в опенсорс.

Comment: @z668 странная логика. меня, например, больше напрягает когда человек пишет "привет!, заранее спасибо!", потом пишет "вы меня просто спасли!" и ... не нажимает ни плюс, ни mark as answer. Кстати, хэшкод - а где это?

Comment: @PashaPash, hashcode.ru Сейчас домен редиректит на RU SO.

Comment: @z668 я к тому, что я сюда пришел с англиского SO. и Athari тоже, насколько я знаю. Для меня странно, что кто-то ожидает что тут будет не SO, а, например, хэшкод. Если бы правила и ламповость хэшкода делали его объективно лучше, чем SO, то это это хэшкод бы втянул в себя SO, а не наоборот.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну с английского SO тут не вы одни. Но пришествие с оного не означает, что нам нужно тупо всё клонировать. У нас другая по размеру и по составу аудитория и это стоит учитывать. Не все правила SO EN необходимы, как мне кажется.

Comment: @ixSci то же самое можно сказать и про правила хэшкода.

Comment: @PashaPash, разумеется. Но в рамках данного вопроса мы рассматриваем вполне конкретное правило, которое, на мой взгляд, можно смягчить в русской части SO. Это не значит, что мы берём его с хэшкод, это значит, что мы идём навстречу людям, которым не нравится их сообщения без приветствия.

Comment: @PashaPash, между нами одна разница - вы тут добровольно, мы тут принудительно. Т.е. в один прекрасный момент хешкод начал редиректить на ru so. И еще дело в том что идти то нам получается кроме ru so  - некуда, старого доброго хешкода уже нет.

Comment: @z668 Почему "доброжелательность" меряется приветствиями — мне понять не дано. Вон, на сайте несколько юзеров ругают новичков за непроходимую тупизну открытым текстом — лучше направить энергию в их сторону. И эти юзеры пришли как раз с "доброжелательного" хэшкода — на "долбаном американском" СО им бы давно влетело от модераторов по первое число. / К слову, тёплые ламповые форумы с приветствиями, благодарностями, флудом и холиварами — живут до сих пор.

Comment: @z668 Спасибо за беспокойство, я оттуда и не уходил. Равно как и с тёплых ламповых форумов, и с коллективных блогов, и с прочих ресурсов. Каждому ресурсу своё.

Comment: @z668 я успел потусоваться в свое время на винграде и на русском мсдн. так вот, хэшкод по сравнению с ними, и даже по сравнению с американским SO - жутко недружелюбное к новичкам место. Такое ощущение, что фанаты теплой ламповой тусовки не понимаю, что 99% задающих вопросы - это новички. И SO не превращается в треш только из-за постоянно вносимых правок в чужие сообщения.

Answer (score 7):

Такой функционал уже есть. Вопрос можно сделать "защищенным" или выставить для него "блок". Отмечать вопросы [защищенными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) могут все пользователи, набравшие 3.5К баллов репутации. Выставлять блок, на сколько я могу судить, только модераторы.

Добавление атрибута защиты к вопросу, не поможет в данном случае, так как такие вопросы защищены только от новичков, не набравших 10 баллов репутации.

Как ни странно, даже на ХэшКоде модераторы (в частности я) убирали приветствия из сообщений. Например, при редактировании, я всегда удалял "заранее спасибо" и аналогичные выражения, а также не обходил стороной долгих вступлений. Как уже было замечено, что на ХэшКоде, что на Stack Overflow на русском подобные правки являются лишь дополнением к каким-то другим, более серьезным. То есть вероятность правки вопроса без ошибок, но с "добрыми приветствиями" крайне низкая.

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что [данный вопрос рассматривался на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/) до того, как вносились правки. Сообщество единогласно согласилось в том, что излишнюю доброжелательность *можно* опускать.

---

Объединение проектов произошло не потому что кто-то прав или не прав в вопросе правки. Оно произошло потому что у ХэшКода и Stack Overflow одна и та же миссия. Было бы ошибкой терять накопленную базу знаний и превосходное сообщество знатоков ХэшКода.

Stack Overflow на русском отличается от ХэшКода более продвинутым движком и новой аудиторией. На самом деле оба фактора сильно влияют на жизнь участников. Например, раньше пользователи на порядок реже принимали участие в правке содержимого, чем сейчас, так как не было очередей проверок.

Конечно, после перехода в сообществе произошли изменения, но все эти изменения происходят по инициативе *пользователей*. Более того, за сайтом наблюдают те же модераторы, что и раньше. Если вы не согласны с какими-либо новым поведением, пожалуйста, публикуйте ваш вопрос здесь, на Мете.

Comment: Про "единогласно" - вы не правы: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/94/6545

Comment: @z668 Единогласия нет, но мнение большинства и администрации налицо.

Answer (score 5):

Если вас зацепило моей лавиной правок меток, то могу дать один действенный совет, чтобы избавиться от моих правок:

1. использовать правильные метки;
2. правильно форматировать сообщение;
3. соблюдать прочие правила ресурса (про оффтопик, в частности).

Исключительно ради удаления приветствий и благодарностей править сообщение, скорее всего, мне будет лень (если они не написаны жирным капсом в несколько строчек). А если у сообщения проблемы с метками и форматированием, то я буду его механически исправлять, а запоминать личные предпочтения десятков пользователей, которые идут вразрез с правилами — это мне тоже лень. Когда правишь сотни сообщений подряд, следить за авторством сообщений нет ни желания, ни возможности, уж извините.

И тут возможность отката предлагали — это тоже не лучшая идея, потому что, если исправленные теги будут испорчены, я с большой вероятностью появлюсь снова.

Answer (score 4):

*Попробую ответить на поставленный z668 вопрос с другой стороны.*

Не забывайте, что SO в первую очередь это база знаний вопросов и ответов, а не взаимоотношений пользователей.

Ваши вопросы не являются какими-то особенными. Они точно так же как и все остальные должны отвечать правилам и обычаям сайта. В противном случае они могут корректироваться, получать голоса, и даже удаляться.

Правки Athari так же делаются в соответствии с правилами и нормами сайта (см. вопросы на Мета про приветствия). На месте Athari будут другие корректоры. Если вы считаете такие правки неверными и нарушающими правила сайта - укажите такое правило.

Добавление индивидуальных преференций отвечающих личным интересам пользователей в ущерб наполнению сайта - не пройдет.

Comment: Честно сказать надоела эта демагогия. Либо жесткая монархия со стороны администрации, либо коллективное голосование (опрос) - только тогда будет ясность. В предыдущем вопросе так ничего и не решили толком. Третьего не дано.

Comment: Ваш комментарий не относится к ответу, но отвечу - Опрос был проведен на английском SO и тут в мете. Результаты вы можете посмотреть - большинство за удаление "шума".

Comment: Русская и Английская мета - разные. Почему не сделать опрос в русской мете? Будут результаты опроса - будет и адекватное решение. На данный момент мы просто тупо передираем правила с английской меты без собственных голосований.

Comment: Чем вам прилинкованый вопрос не опрос (со счетом 12/6), или нужно устроить референдум с транспарантами на всю шапку? :-)

Comment: Лучше - второе =)

Comment: @z668: Потрудитесь пожалуйста комментировать по теме ответа. А то вы себя же дискредитируете.

Comment: а что тут по теме можно прокомментировать? Я даже свой! вопрос удалить не могу. У меня своя точка зрения. Я не поменял своего мнения. Вижу только одно - правила тупо слизаны с большого SO, и всем по большему счету плевать на это. Доказывать что-то\навязывать своем мнение кому то - бессмысленно. Нет ни нормальных опросов, ни жестких позиций администрации.

Comment: @z668: Перечитайте пожалуйста ответ, с чем конкретно в нем вы не согласны или что хотите уточнить комментариями? P.S. Приглашение в чат выше вы проигнорировали, дальше вести здесь дискуссию не буду.

Comment: @z668 не стоит искать в каждом правиле происки госдепа. вырезание приветствий обсуждалось на русской мете буквально месяц назад, с честным голосованием. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/ ссылка на него висела на основном сайте в правой части. там нет ни одного голоса против ответа "удалять!". хотите - проголосуйте против. тут честные голосования - это ж амерский сайт :)

Answer (score 3):

**Athari** всё делает правильно. В частности приветствия в начале сообщения и прочие "спасибо" в конце сообщения запрещены правилами StackOverflow. (Они не содержат информацию относящуюся к вопросу).

Пожайлуйста привыкайте к новым правилам.

Comment: @z668, дополню, что тут посыл не в том, что "вежливость не нужна", а в том, что вопросы в будущем будут читаться другими юзерами, которым надо найти решение их проблемы, и для них все эти приветствия выглядят так же как если бы в энциклопедии каждая статья началась бы с "здравствуйте, вот есть такая проблема"

Comment: Abyx, тем не менее иногда хочется поблагодарить человека, который безвозмездно помогает. В итоге даже запретили сказать банальное "Спасибо за помощь".

Comment: @Abyx когда читаешь энциклопедию, то автор в ней обезличен - это сухая информация, но читая вопросы мы видим конкретный ник и ники отвечающих. Это - личности, а для личности нормально выразить свое приветствие. У нас немного другой менталитет, как мне кажется. У русских принято приветствовать людей к которым обращаешься.

Comment: ReinRaus, абсолютно с вами согласен.

Comment: @z668 Поставить плюсик и галочку — уже достаточное "спасибо".

Comment: @ReinRaus Дело не в менталитете. На большом СО тоже все добавляют "привет" и "заранее спасибо", просто эти надписи автоматически удаляются движком при отправке вопроса. А у нас эти фильтры ещё не настроили.

Comment: Athari, кому как. Повторюсь - правила хешкода были лучше, лояльнее, добрее.

Comment: @z668 Пожалуйста, используйте обращение с помощью "@", иначе уведомление не доходит.

Comment: @Athari, хорошо.

Comment: @all: Я не думаю, что «спасибо» настолько ухудшает текст вопроса, чтобы аж с этим надо было бороться. **Гораздо** больше его ухудшают, например, вываленные 10 кб кода без объяснений.

Comment: @ReinRaus русские при встрече даже не интересуются how are you. так что не в менталитете дело. это политика конкретного сайта. за и против разобраны в английской мете: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @z668 "спасибо за помощь" можно оставить комментарием. ни разу не видел чтобы такие комментарии удаляли.

Comment: @PashaPash: Английский SO — не русский SO. То, что обсуждено на английской Мете, не обязательно автоматом подходит для нас.

Comment: @VladD я и не предлагал перетягивать оттуда решение. я предлагал почитать аргументы, которые там приведены. Пока единственный аргумент встреченный здесь, которого нет на английской мете - это, якобы, более дружелюбный менталитет русских. Которые почему-то во всем мире считаются злыми, страшными и угрюмыми :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Ясно, согласен с вами. Я не вполне правильно понял ваш комментарий.

Answer (score 3):

@z668, мнение администрации вполне выражено в прошлом вопросе. Если что, администрация - это менеджер сообщества Nicolas Chabanovsky.

Правила удаления вопросов и прочие ограничения возможностей не "слизаны". Мы теперь просто используем другой движок со всеми его возможностями и ограничениями. Это данность, "поменять в исходниках" логику мы не можем.

Правила взаимодействия пользователей на социальном уровне и традиции мы можем обсуждать и менять. Но, как тут уже говорили, "здраствуйте" и "спасибо" не сильно приветствовались и раньше, т.к. и бывший ХэшКод и SO - это прежде всего **коллективно редактируемые** базы знаний, а не уютненькие форумы или архивы куртуазной переписки.

Возможная мягкость старого ХэшКода была связана с недостаточностью инструментария, не позволявшей вовлекать участников сообщества в заботу о самом сообществе.

---

PS. Не понятна и ваша открытая неприязнь к "амерскому" SO. StackOverflow это прежде всего международное англоязычное сообщество. Теперь есть его версии и на других языках (японский, португальский). Если такие уважаемые имена как Джоэл Спольски и Джефф Этвуд вам ни о чем не говорят, то показное пренебрежение, не делает вам чести.