# Отклонение правки, убирающей приветствия и благодарности

Tags: обсуждение, предлагаемые-правки, приветствия

Сообщество решило, что [приветствия и благодарности не стоит добавлять в текст сообщений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/95/176217). При этом в смежной теме есть [рекомендация не редактировать сообщение *только* лишь для удаления подобной информации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324/176217). Однако, как я могу видеть, ещё не обсуждался вопрос о том, как следует поступать, если правка, удаляющая приветствия и благодарности требует утверждения.

Моё мнение, что подобную правку однозначно следует утверждать, так как в любом случае она повышает информационную плотность (отношение полезной информации к количеству символов) сообщения.

С другой стороны, поощрять ситуации, когда участник начинает тоннами править древние сообщения только лишь для исключения подобного *шума*, тоже не стоит.

Comment: Понимаю, новогоднее, наболело... Тоже вычищал постоянно.

Comment: @AK не новогоднее. Просто конкретный случай, он мог произойти в совершенно любой день.

Comment: Противоречивое мнение. И да и нет. Получится так, что попросим одного, второго так не делать(не делать правки только ради удаления приветствий), а третий все равно поправит. Лучше пускай правят. Совсем старые сообщения со временем закончатся. И новые по возможности сразу править нужно. И да, информативности от приветствий никакой, лучше пусть авторы лишнюю строчку по делу напишут.

Answer (score 9):

У нас есть два принятых решения:

- Можно и нужно вырезать [Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/)
- До порога правки без ревью - вырезать приветствия *только* [одновременно с исправлением всех остальных проблем поста](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2417/177221).

Ответ, на мой взгляд, прямо следует из этих решений:

- Если кроме приветствий в посте не было других проблем или они также исправлены - принимать правку.
- Если в посте были другие проблемы, и они не исправлены - отклонять правку.

Минорные правки забивают очередь сообщений. Один фармящий +2 участник (запрос по data + вырезание заменой) забивает очередь проверок под завязку.

Вырезание приветов кажется милым, но стоит помнить, что каждые +2 требуют участия еще двух ревьюверов.

Comment: Не согласен. Каждый что может -- то и поправляет. Такое сплошь и рядом бывает, вот например золотое правило в очереди проверок: не уверен -- нажми "пропустить". Тут так же: не правь если не уверен. Состояния на этих плюс два не сделаешь.

Comment: @AK дело в том, что некоторые участники пытались активно сделать состояние на минорны правках. Это не предположение, это реальный факт. Т.е. они целенаправленно искали вопросы с приветами и вырезали только приветы.

Comment: @AK такая ситуация настолько всех достала, что появился вопрос и ответ http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2417/177221

Comment: @PashaPash Хотите личтно вы займитесь этим, удалите такие вопросы на корню? Причём только "привет", "спасибо" и т.д. Я думаю, что вы не захотите. А знаете почему? Потому что это труд.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov а вы не думали, что просмотр очереди проверок (два человека на каждый аппрув вырезания привета) - это тоже труд? За который просматривающие даже +2 не получают? Запрет на минорые правки появился после того, как очередной фармер забил очередь вырезанием "привет". И остальным участникам просто надоело видеть такие "полуправки".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вот вам конкретный пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/57198 - правка вырезала "привет". Читабельность сообщения улучшилась?

Comment: @PashaPash Ну пусть тоже потрудятся. Давайте каждый будет вносить вклад в чистоту. Что плохого в этом? Зато точно будет чище и лучше.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov у меня сложилось впечатление, что вы не вчитываетесь в мои ответы на мете, или что я как-то их криво формулирую :( Уже 3-й раз за пару дней понимаете их с точностью до наоборот. У меня в ответе написано - **да, приветствия надо вырезать**. Не понимаю, в чем вы меня пытаетесь убедить. В том, что приветствия надо вырезать?

Comment: @PashaPash Я просто говорю своё мнение: не считаю нужным отклонять правку, которая просто удаляет приветствия. Даже если там всё остальное просто ужас. И ничего страшного, что проверяющий потрудится тоже. И ничего страшного даже если человек исправит так даже 1000 вопросов/ответов и получит кучу репутации.  Это будет честно. И ничего, что в очереди проверки будут эти вопросы/ответы.

Comment: Была дискусия на эту тему) Мое мнение прежнее, по возможности **приветствия и спасибо удалять**, правки принимать. Каждый участник делает вопрос/ответ лучше так, как он это видит. Всегда будет существовать вероятность, что даже после правки можно улучшить q/a, в данном случае в очереди правок есть кнопка **улучшить правку**. Если кроме таких слов править нечего, то можно и их убрать как лишнюю информацию. Со временем вопросов с таким текстом становится меньше. В идеале нужно сделать спасок стоп слов при отправке вопроса/ответа/косментария.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov дело в том, что и вы, и A K говорите о волне таких правок как о некой теоретической ситуации. "Если" человек предложит, то "ничего страшного, проверяющий потрудится". А я и Qwertiy с такой ситуацией реально сталкивались. Первые 20-30-40 таких правок - проходят нормально. Но потом вы заметите, что вы видите в очереди проверок *только* вырезания приветов. Если хотите - могу реально такую ситуацию создать - 4984 спасибо и 3442 привета в очереди правок быстро заставят вас изменить свое мнение. Будете аппрувить только приветы ближайшие 250 дней :)

Comment: И пусть. Тут не так и много вопросов. Давайте вместе наводить порядок. Плюс каждый понемногу возьмёт на себя и потянем. Такие вопросы всё равно не бесконечны. И пусть так и будет, сможете 50 правок в день и всё, отдыхайте. Дальше очередь просмотрят другие.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov дело в том, что кто-то "берет на себя", а кто-то воспринимает это как "фарм +2 на мелочи". никто не против наведения порядка - но стоит поощерять тех, кто действительно наводит порядок, а не просто нашел способ "легко" зарабатывать репутацию за счет труда проверяющих.

Answer (score 6):

Я в поздравлениях этих не вижу ничего полезного, всё это -- оффтопик, их нужно резать, резать и резать. ;)

Насколько у меня сложилось понимание правил, рекомендация "отклонять зарезание поздравлений" сделана лишь для того, чтобы снизить нагрузку на проверяющих правки. См. например вопрос про [незначительные правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1951/): у меня например рука на автопилоте тянется поправить пару опечаток в тексте. И я знаю, что особо никому чистота языка не нужна на ru-so, мы тут не филологи собрались, но если репутация позволяет быстро поправить, не отвлекая никого - то почему бы и нет?

Поэтому если репутация позволяет -- можно и нужно вырезать все эти поздравления, никого этим вы не отвлекаете.

А те, кто пытается править ещё не достигнув уровня репутации - делают хорошее дело, потому что снимают нагрузку с тех, кто мог бы сам порезать поздравлялки, да нет времени или неохота (т.е. те, кто могут -- не справляются).

Поэтому правки такие нужно одобрять: кнопку "принять" нажать секундное дело, а дело делается благое.

Answer (score 4):

Я за такие правки (удаление приветствий) даже в древних сообщениях и в любых количествах. Не понимаю либеральности общественности насчёт этих приветствий.

Вижу попытку протащить даже требование и создать правило "чтобы не править приветствия", хотя, уверен, что неверно.

Здесь база знаний, а не форум. И здесь "Здравствуйте", "Добрый день!", "Спасибо", "Буду благодарен за любую помощь" неуместны.

---

Правку сообщений считаю тоже трудом, поэтому каждый участник правивший любое сообщение (даже 2011 года) достоин +2 за каждую правку. Даже если это единственная правка и больше ничего не поправлено.

Comment: Вопрос alexolut не о том, оставлять ли приветствия. Если бы это было так - то его бы закрыли как дубликат. Вопрос о том, что делать с правками, содержащими только вырезание приветствий, при просмотре очереди правок (внесенных участниками с низкой репутацией)

Comment: @PashaPash Так я же написал: "Я **за** такие правки". А значит считаю, что они достойны +2 к репутации.

Comment: а если при этом в посте все остальные проблемы остались неисправленными? все равно +2?

Comment: @PashaPash Вот это уж точно не проблема! Каждый что может -- то и поправляет. Такое сплошь и рядом бывает, вот например золотое правило в очереди проверок: не уверен -- нажми "пропустить". Тут так же: не правь если не уверен. Состояния на этих плюс два не сделаешь.

Comment: @AK вы не поверите, есть люди которые фармят на +2 до самого лимита. Полная очередь проверок с вырезанными приветами и кривым форматированием

Comment: @PashaPash Отписал свою позицию.

Comment: Я не модератор, у меня веры в добрые намерения людей намного больше ;)

Comment: @AK причем тут вера? это не теоретическая ситуация, такое тут уже не раз случалось :)

Answer (score 1):

На английском SO считается правильным такие правки отклонять, чтобы не забивать очереди.

И я с этим согласен. Точнее, я вообще против вырезания приветствий. Но заставлять ещё 3*n человек посмотреть, как ты умеешь вырезать приветствия - это уж совсем. Если поотклонять такие правки, то у человека отпадёт желание таким образом бесполезно забивать очереди. Для правок можно найти и что-то пополезнее.

Comment: Хорошо бы ссылку на enSO. И почему 3, если 2? Кол-во проверяющих ничтожно по сравнению с кол-вом тех, кто будет наблюдать сообщение в процессе его существования. Более того, проверяющие осознанно идут на этот шаг.

Comment: @alexolut, там для такого причина отклонения типа too minor или что-то такое. Не помню, это искать надо. Про 3, наверное, ошибся.

Comment: @alexolut 3 потому что бывает +-, в таких случаях нужен 3 проверяющий

Comment: @Qwertiy очередь все равно будет, т.к. приходят новые участники. я лично за год очень мало видел правок из удаленных лишних фраз. К тому же с достаточной репутацией редактирование идет минуя очередь проверок и если не загубить желание редакторов чистить вопросы, они и дальше будут этим заниматься(если наберут репу конечно), только уже минуя очередь. А если загубить на корню, то у них будет еще меньше желания что-то делать и кто тогда будет редактировать? это конечно же не говорит о том, что я за то, чтобы репутация для прямого редактирования набиралась только за счет правок )