# Нужна ли автоматическая резка приветствий?

Tags: предложение, правки, приветствия

На оригинальном SO невозможно запостить вопрос, который начинается с приветствия, например "Hi!", "Hello" или "Good day". Я периодически делаю правки, удаляющие приветствие из вопросов, но их слишком много - наследие форумной культуры. Стоит ли нам тоже автоматизировать этот процесс, или лучше просто сдаться на милость "доброму времени суток"?

Связанный вопрос: [Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/93/181472)

Comment: А как автоматизировать? Завести список **всех** приветствий? Начиная с «Добрый день, уважаемые форумчане», и заканчивая «Хей пипл»?

Comment: @VladD да, что-то в этом духе. У нас же есть база вопросов - можно исследовать ее и вырезать наиболее часто используемые приветствия с вариациями через регулярки.

Comment: @VladD в конце концов, задача - изменить ожидания пользователей. Если мы вырежем хотя бы 90%, новые пользователи поймут, что приветствия не нужны

Comment: Может, тогда просто детектировать приветствия на стороне клиента и выводить подсказку в окне редактирования «у нас тут приветствия не приняты, пишите сразу по делу»?

Comment: Это я о технической стороне вопроса, нужны ли традиционные форумные приветствия или нет, вопрос дискуссионный. Я бы относился к ним либеральнее, т. к. они всё же часть традиционной форумной культуры, и ограничился бы предупреждением.

Comment: @VladD ЕМНИП на SO это на стороне клиента и работает

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется, что большинство приветствий и мольб о помощи можно детектировать поиском

```
здрав
привет
уважае
помоги
помощ
дорог
добр
пожал
срочн
всем
```

по первым 15-20 символам вопроса, если эти слова в блоке кода или цитате, то детектировать не надо.
На стороне клиента сделать плашку про приветствия и мольбы, и по-возможности подсветить слово на которое сработал детектор.

Answer (score 2):

*Данное сообщение является копией вопроса «[Заменить автоматическое удаление приветствий на недопущение публикации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6680/208074)», помещённой сюда [по просьбе Николаса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6680/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8#comment27518_6680).*

---

Недавно была предложена инициатива «[Автоматическое удаление приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6666/208074)».

В связи с [высказанными опасениями](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6671/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9#comment26087_6674):

> Так все зависит от того, какая регулярка. Русский язык, к сожалению, куда богаче английского. Если хватит воли создать километровую регулярку, которая корректно будет вырезать вещи типа "Приветствую вас, уважаемые знатоки", то нет вопросов. А если она будет превращать это в "вас, уважаемые знатоки", заставляя думать что курил автор, (и вопрос все равно придется править вручную), тогда какой смысл?

Предлагаю не вырезать ключевые слова, а попросту не давать публиковать сообщения с ними по аналогии с запретом на короткие тексты.

Тогда можно будет:

- сократить список ключевых слов, убрав оттуда различные варианты одной и той же фразы (пример: `доброе утро всем`, `добрый вечер всем` и `добрый вечер коллеги` дублируют `доброе утро` и `добрый вечер`),
- не ломать голову насчёт смысловой корректности частей,остающихся после отрезания.

Вот пример того, как это могло бы выглядеть:

> [image: Запрет приветствий при задании вопроса]

Answer (score 0):

IMHO.

От особо оголтелых приветствий нужно отучать.

"Всем привет" или "Hi, All" - да и фиг с ними.

Но на самом деле всё, что мы тут обсуждаем, уйдёт в /dev/null, потому что есть Начальство SO, которое лучше знает, как им индексироваться в поисковиках и что нужно делать на пути к статусу Единого И Всеобщего Списка Вопросов И Ответов. А тема эта - не более чем дань вежливости сообществу :)

Comment: На самом деле "Начальства" нет. Большенство функционала согласуется с сообществом. Что касается приветствий, то эта подсистема называется "Проверка Качества". Просто еще нет ее реализации для русского языка.

Comment: Про этот AI я в чате писал как-то. Когда не мог простой вопрос на мету запостить. Опять же, IMHO, но рановато автоматическое что-либо вводить, пока оно на таком уровне.