# Автоматическое удаление приветствий

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, приветствия

Спешу предложить собрать список слов, которые будут *автоматически удаляться из сообщения во время отправки сообщения на сервер*. На данный момент подобная функция [доступна в англоязычном сообществе](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/274323). Ниже регулярное выражение для английского языка.

```
^                 # в начале тела вопроса
\s*               # пробелы
(
hii?(?![a-z])|    # любое из следующих приветственных слов
hello|
h(e|a)y(?![a-z])|
dear|
greetings|
hai|
guys|
howdy|
h(i|e)ya|
hola
)
.*?               # далее все, что угодно до...
(
[.,;!-]+          # какого–либо знака припинания
\s*               # возможные пробелы
|
(\r?\n)+          # один или несколько переносов строки.
)
```

Для нас будет отрабатывать, по сути, то же регулярное выражение, но с другим списком слов.

**Обновление**

Ниже представлена статистика по употреблению для наиболее популярных приветствий. Приветствия искал самым простым запросом на внутренним аналоге [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/):

```
SELECT count(p.Id) as NumberOfOccurrences
FROM Posts p
WHERE LOWER(p.Body) LIKE N'%добрый день%'
and p.PostTypeId = 1
```

Данные:

- «здравствуйте» — 18 747.
- «привет» — 12 045.
- «добрый день» — 9 792.
- «доброго» — 7 284.
- «приветствую» — 1 682.
- «всем добр» — 1 535.
- «добрый вечер» — 1 455.
- «уважаемые» — 1 178.
- «день добрый» — 425.
- «доброе утро» — 116.
- «всем добра» — 64.
- «всем доброе» — 44.

На основе этих данных, регулярное выражение для нашего сайта будет выглядеть следующим образом (пожалуйста, проверьте!). Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что предположительно оставив 5 основных типов приветствий мы покроем основную массу сообщений, и по максимуму избежим ошибок, так как представленные приветствия самостоятельные и неоднозначностей с ними нет. Пожалуйста, если вы видите ошибку в выражении, напишите об этом в ответом. Буду также признателен за любую подсказку как улучшить регулярное выражение (примеры употреблений можно посмотреть используя поиск по сайту с модификатором `is:question body:приветствие`).

```
^                 # в начале тела вопроса
\s*               # пробелы
(
здравствуйте|    # любое из следующих приветственных слов
привет|
добрый|
доброго|
приветствую
)
.*?               # далее все, что угодно до...
(
[.,;!-]+          # какого–либо знака припинания
\s*               # возможные пробелы
|
(\r?\n)+          # один или несколько переносов строки.
)
```

Если в ближайшее время не будет серьезных замечаний, мы добавим регулярное выражение на сайт.

**Обновление**

Сегодня в ночь с 23 на 24 апреля 2018 года обновили настройки, добавив предложенное регулярное выражение. Давайте вместе наблюдать, как идет эксперимент! Если вы заметили что–то плохое или хорошее, пожалуйста, дайте знать в комментариях к этому вопросу или ответом в [Нужна ли автоматическая резка приветствий?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/465/)

Comment: Одобряю, давно пора всё это под нож автоматически пускать.

Comment: А я по-прежнему против. Приветствия не мешают. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6671/178988

Comment: Не думаю, что это вообще хорошая идея

Comment: Надо бы еще из хвоста удалять «заранее спасибо» и прочие «буду благодарен».

Comment: Я тоже против, поясню своё мнение. Приветствие может быть разное, иногда это просто желание эпотажа, покрасоваться. Но иногда это выражение чувств человека, его настроения, он хочет проявиться, раскрыться на сайте. Не только технически сухо спросить но и выразить свои эмоции, например хорошее настроение. Если это урезать, то сайт станет более сухим и чёрствым. У многих технарей и так проблемы есть с выражением чувств, так зачем это ещё усугублять и усиливать. Понятное дело что SO это сайт по техническим вопросам и ответам, но чуть-чуть просто общения не помешает а наоборот поможет сайту быть б

Comment: Номер еще классный выдали этому вопросу.

Comment: По итогам ещё [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/465/176217) красную метку стоит впендюрить.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Приношу свои извинения, но это не дискуссия о том, плохо это или хорошо, это лишь сбор стоп–слов для регулярного выражения. Пожалуйста, если у вас есть мысли на этот счет, задайте отдельный вопрос или допишите ответ к уже существующему обсуждению (эта тема затрагивалась ни один раз!)

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин приветы — мусор, никак не влияющий на какие-то там чувства. Разбавлять «сухость» можно кучей других способов, например [«табличками», «запихиваниями» и прочими разговорными фразами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/575919), [шуточными угрозами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739736), [лулзами в зачёркиваниях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764360), [ностальгией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733042) и так далее

Comment: @andreymal я согласен, я однозначно против мусора, но нормальноые выражение человеческих чувств, например "спасибо, работает!" под резку по моему мнению пускать не стоит.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ну это уже не приветы всё-таки) По задумке «спасибы» это зелёные галочки слева от ответов, но лично я не имею какого-то однозначного мнения о нужности «спасибок»-текстов, в отличие от приветов

Comment: @andreymal возможно я слишком резко выразил своё мнение, думаю от убирание приветов особо хуже не станет, но не уверен что хорошая мысль делать это автоматикой, так как привет привету рознь, но если писать предупреждение пользователю (но не как обязаловку а как рекомендацию), тогда я полностью за. напрягает обязаловка и механический подход, так как в этом случае под обрезку может попасть и адекватный текст

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин есть какие-нибудь реальные примеры, когда «добрый день» или другое похожее приветствие в начале сообщения не заслуживает удаления?

Comment: @andreymal Вот реальный пример  - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767238/asp-net-webapi-winforms сообщение приятно читать, удалив начальное приветствие и конечно спасибо, будет уже не то

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин не согласен, первое и последнее предложения мусор и их можно смело удалять

Comment: @andreymal ваше мнение я уважаю, и понимаю что для вас это может быть пустой информацией. Для меня же это полезная информация.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин что конкретно объективно полезного вы потеряли бы, если бы не прочитали "доброго времени суток" и "спасибо"?

Comment: @andreymal тут написал - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6683/205037

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это только по приветствиям или ко всем лишним, например "спасибо", "заранее благодарен", "прошу помощи" и т.п. ?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky и еще, м.б. стоит рассмотреть вариант предупреждения пользователя о том, что в тексте слова из стоп-листа(например добавить бинд на js, на ввод). Т.е. если автор ввел слово из стоп-листа, отображать ему предупреждение , о том, что в тексте слово "Привет" (пример), которое будет удалено. Отображать можно сразу или перед публикацией вопроса.

Comment: А как быть, например, с - "Добрый день, господа!"? Судя по regexp останется - "господа!".

Comment: Хм, а я ещё думал, может всё-таки стоит начинать вопрос/ответ с какого-нибудь приветствия, а оказывается тут это не любят. И, да, предупреждать пользователя о том, что некоторые слова из его текста будут удалены не помешает.

Comment: Против. ИМХО, приветствие, ежели оно приличное и не чрезвычайно кустистое, не мешает.

Comment: Думаю, единственным нормальным исключением может быть прямое обращение к конкретной части аудитории, например: "Коллеги, кто пользовался сайтом squarespace..."

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А не скажите, почему не сделано автоматическое удаление комментариев вроде "спасибо" когда я их помечаю флагом? Я полагаю, что это смежная проблема, связанная с удалением ненужного шума с постов. На enSO такое уже довольно давно работает.

Answer (score 15):

Список слов:

- ауе братва
- вечер в хату
- вечер добрый
- всем дарова
- всем добра
- всем доброе утро
- всем добрый день
- всем добрый вечер
- всем доброго времени суток
- всем здарова
- всем здравствуйте
- всем привет
- всем приветики
- всем приветы
- всем салам
- всем хай
- дарова
- дарова всем
- день добрый
- добра
- добрейший вечерочек
- доброго времени суток
- доброго утра
- доброе утро
- доброе утро всем
- доброй ночи
- добрый вечер
- добрый вечер всем
- добрый вечер коллеги
- добрый день
- добрый день коллеги
- драсти
- дратути
- зарание спасибо
- заранее спасибо
- здарова
- здарова бандиты
- здарова всем
- здарова парни
- здарова ребята
- здравствуйте
- здравствуйте все
- здравствуйте коллеги
- здрасте
- коллеги
- коллеги приветствую
- мир вам
- привет
- привет всем
- прифки
- приветик
- приветики
- приветики всем
- приветствую
- приветствую коллеги
- приветствую всех вошедших
- приветы
- салам
- спасибо
- спс
- ув коллеги
- уважаемые знатоки
- уважаемые коллеги
- утро доброе
- хай
- хай всем
- хаюхай
- хаю-хай
- хеллоу
- хелоу

Comment: спасиба за доброго времени суток

Comment: еще дратути добавьте)

Comment: @Cypher Пожалуйста, вносите любые варианты!

Comment: Я так понимаю, по итогам нужно будет родить какие-то более общие шаблонные наборы?

Comment: @alexolut Необходимо будет задать регулярное выражение, подобное тому, что в вопросе.

Comment: @Cypher Для информации, на сайте в данный момент нет ни одного использования слова "дратути". Если вы хотите запихать сюда все возможные способы безграмотно написать слово "здравствуйте", боюсь регулярка получится слишком длинной...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Вероятно, мы можем собрать совсем все в этом ответе. Вторым шагом будет проверка количества сообщений в базе с конкретными фразами. После, возьмем, к примеру, 10 наиболее распространенных.

Comment: А где "хаюхай с вами Ива..." ? ))

Comment: Ещё "прифки" и "хелоу" забыли (

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Вопрос общий. Пожалуйста, вносите все, что считаете разумным рассматривать!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky всё, добавил )

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Большое спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да ладно, что тут, не за что ;)

Comment: хеллоу ворлд???

Comment: Заран[ие]е спасибо

Comment: @insolor На сколько я понимаю, на данный момент, у нас есть возможность вырезать только приветствие в начале сообщения.

Comment: Надо к этому добавить еще и англоязычные приветствия. Сейчас люди умные - на английском начнут общаться)

Comment: Я считаю что нужно вырезать тупые приветствия, сигнализирующие о проблемах с головой у ТС, типа "приффки", "дратути" и т.д. В "добрый вечер" и "здравствуйте" проблем не вижу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это был намёк на альтернативное написание фразы "заранее спасибо" в ответе)

Comment: @DaemonHK, вы чего, какая нагрузка на сервера-то будет с таким многообразием приветствий) Теперь все будут присать не "привет", а "првт")))

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский а вот за такой перебор можно и вопрос удалять будет))

Comment: @insolor тогда уж и "за раннее спасибо"

Comment: Преведствия на падонкафскам языге не учтены, гыыыыыыыыыы

Comment: @РашенБеар Подскажите, пожалуйста, на сколько это критично?

Comment: А как же могли забыть "Хола", "Ку" :C

Comment: "Прошу сильно не пинать", "я новичок" (и "я новичек"), и т. п.

Answer (score -3):

Добрый вечер.
Чтобы не растягивать код предлагаю не вырезать четыре варианта приветствия, а вот остальные удалять.

Оставить:
"Доброе утро",
"Добрый день",
"Добрый вечер",
"Здравствуйте"

> На данный момент подобная функция доступна в англоязычном сообществе

Не надо во всём подражать, это глупо.

Answer (score -4):

Хе-хе. Господа удаляльщики слов! Вам еще придется перебрать все варианты, когда в кириллическом слове ставят похожую по начертанию букву на латинице. Например, в слове "Спасибо" можно написать [с], [а], и [о] на латинице. А также все сочетания Це из Эн по Ка. Займитесь, напишите бота который вас будет радовать своими успехами. А может проще не заниматься ерундой? Приветствия это часть стандарта письменного общения на русском языке. Отродясь они никому не мешали, и вот вдруг в 2018 году от Рождества Христова на сайте стековерфлоу приветствия стали мешать паре гиков с проблемами социальной адаптированности. Самим-то не смешно?

UPD1:

Есть хороший способ - кто не может выносить вида слова "Здравствуйте", тот просто не заходит в те вопросы, которые начинаются со слова "Здравствуйте", не отвечает на них, и вообще не смотрит в ту сторону. Свобода в том, что Вы можете не ходить туда, где вам неприятно. В интернете такая свобода тем более есть. Просто игнорируйте все вежливые вопросы. Кстати, если на стековерфлоу отменяют правила вежливости, означает ли это, что теперь на стековерфлоу можно употреблять нецензурную лексику? Не написать ли бота, который рандомно вставляет матерные слова в текст вопросов? Ну мало ли, может кому-то нравится так общаться. Обсудите там, идея вполне в русле удаления слова "Здравствуйте".

Comment: Совершенно согласен, что убивать в это столько усилий это пустая трата времени. Более того: делать предлагаемые правки, которые исключительно выпиливают приветствия, *не рекомендуется* (их могут отклонить по "не содержит никаких улучшений" и будут правы). Но вот между отсутствием явной вежливости и явной грубостью есть разница. Так что в последнем абзаце нет смысла. Придумайте аналогию получше. Ну или уберите его вовсе, если его нечем подкрепить.

Comment: По-моему, заниматься ерундой - это как раз писать "спасибо" наполовину кириллицей, наполовину латиницей. Мне, например, попадались вопросы, которые наполовину состояли из приветствий, прощаний и "прошу сильно не пинать". Пока продерешься и найдешь, где, собственно, вопрос начинается, вечер настанет.

Comment: [Пока продерешься и найдешь, где, собственно, вопрос начинается, вечер настанет.] Каждый может не отвечать на те вопросы, которые ему непонятны и/или неприятны. Каждый может задавать вопросы в той форме, которая наиболее полно отвечает его представлению о прекрасном. Это все не поводы редактировать чужие мысли в каком-то одному модеру известном направлении. Сегодня модеру не понравились приветствия.А если завтра модеру не понравятся деепричастные обороты?Мол они замедляют развитие действия. Что за постановка вопроса - редактировать чужие вопросы?Вы что, лучше знаете что человек хочет спросить?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 раз уж вы спросили, да, [случается, что знаем лучше](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181100), и нередко.

Comment: Если Вы не можете понять вопрос, то так и скажите человеку. Пусть он сам поправит, если сочтет нужным. Но править чужие вопросы это полный бред. Если Вы не можете понять вопрос, то вполне можете на него не отвечать. Но самому поправить вопрос, чтобы довести его до такого состояния, что вы можете на него ответить это более чем странно. Если так делать, тогда на все вопросы в мире сможет ответить любой сержант ГИБДД. Просто в вопросе "как написать шаблон класса?" он поправит несколько слов, чтобы вопрос звучал "можно ли поворачивать налево из среднего ряда?".

Comment: @pepsicoca1 так и скажите, что с [вопросом по ссылке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181100) не ознакомились.