# Не делать автоматическое удаление приветствий

Tags: обсуждение, приветствия

Недавно была предложена вот такая инициатива ([Автоматическое удаление приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6666)).

В связи с этим, у меня встречное предложение - не надо делать автоматическое удаление приветствий.

Comment: Я свою позицию написал тут - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6670/205037

Comment: Связанные вопросы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93 и  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6666

Comment: [«приветы — мусор»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9#comment26059_6666)

Comment: Привет, здравствуй, и добрый вечер, с Новым Годом!! Коллега, салам, день добрейший! Спешу добавить очень ценный комментарий! https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2527/177188

Comment: @Kromster, на который есть не менее ценный ответ: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2520/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9/2527#comment19142_2527

Comment: @Qwertiy вы со мной не поздоровались! :-(

Comment: @Qwertiy если вы позволите, давайте добавим к вопросу контекст

Comment: А чем это обсуждение отличается от предыдущих? Почему нужно отвечать тут, а не там? Кстати, здрасьте кого не видел.

Comment: @defaultlocale, отвечать можно везде где вопросы не закрыты ;) Конкретно это отличается тем, что здесь обсуждается _автоматическое_ удаление движком. Т. е. ты постишь одн текст, он где-то по пути обрабатывается и пуьликуется другой. Даже без записи в истории.

Comment: @Qwertiy обсуждение автоматического удаления [тоже есть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9). Конкретные аргументы весьма разумны, но только в вопросе про них ничего не написано.

Comment: @defaultlocale, нет, там не обсуждение: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD20q.png

Comment: @Qwertiy понятно, спасибо! Только странно что предпосылок нет в самом вопросе, не у всех же есть 10к репы и/или бубен.

Comment: В разных темах предложено много разных мыслей и идей, почему этого делать не стоит, хорошо бы это вместе собрать не в виде ссылок, а цитатами.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, согласен, ответ запостишь? :)

Comment: @Qwertiy думаю тут лучше вместе делать, и ответ сделать общим. Каждый кто видел, писал ответ на эту тему сможет его добавить в общий ответ. Нужно что бы кто-то начал. Возможно я смогу начать, но не прямо сейчас. Так же предлагаю в общем ответе давать ссылки на цитируемое сообщение.

Comment: Со своей стороны хочу сказать что не хочется превращать эту тему в войну )). И лайкать все сообщения которые в свою сторону и дизлайкать противоположенную. То есть смотреть по реальной пользе идеи и сообщения. И найти наилучшее решение для всех.

Comment: Человечность нынче не в моде! Как робот задал вопрос, получил ответ!  А вообще пора бы уже нейронные сети сюда привлекать, чтобы на основании существующий вопросов и ответов, а также ресурсов всего интернета, создавать свои вопросы\ответы. Программисты, просто, будут пользоваться поиском. Накрутка голосов и посетителей за счет ботов.

Comment: @HamSter, пойдите дальше. SO, пользуясь всем могуществом гугла вычисляет еще не заданные конкретным программистом вопросы и назойливо выдает ответы на них во всех открываемых несчастным страницах (как контекстную рекламу)

Answer (score 8):

Почему бы не автоматизировать то, что можно автоматизировать? Приветствия выпиливаются в большинстве своём из любых сообщений вручную, но это приводит к поднятию вопросов, которое некоторые не любят. При автоматическом удалении этих поднятий не будет. Разве же это не хорошо?

Удаление приветствий приветствуется (как бы тавтологично это не звучало), а вот возвращение их назад — воспринимается как вандализм. Приветствия не несут никакой смысловой нагрузки. Об этом уже много сказано в смежных сообщениях. Приведу еще раз сегодня (в первый раз она была под удаленным ныне сообщением в качестве [комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9#comment26051_6669)) цитату на [сообщение из чата](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=41210774#41210774):

> Приветствую вас, собравшиеся здесь по делу и во имя развлечения и успокоения; добрый день жителям Востока, добрый вечер жителям западной России и доброе утро жителям западного полушария; мир вашему дому, благосостояние и божье благословение! Думаю, по этому сообщению видна бессмысленность приветствий в комментариях. Благодарю и низко раскланиваюсь за уделённое сему комментарию дражайшее время каждого, кто изволил ознакомится с сим письменным изложением недостойных внимания мыслей.

Возможно, есть опасения, что автоматические правки могут вырезать что-то полезное. Допускаю, что такое может случиться. На MSE вот недавно поднимался вопрос [Should the word “hay” not be deleted at the beginning of posts, especially on Spanish SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304996/339911) о недопустимости вырезания слова «hay» как приветствия на испаноязычном сайте. Сейчас проблема устранена, и я считаю, довольно быстро. Для нас же подобная ситуация не должна возникнуть в принципе, из-за использования другого алфавита. А вот чтобы она не возникла с русскими словами как раз и предлагается наполнить [список](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6666/176217) стоп-слов совместными усилиями и таким образом, чтобы минимизировать (в идеале, исключить) количество ложных срабатываний.

При этом, если же по какой-то причине автоудаление приветствий кажется нежелательным, стоит развернуть свою мысль чуть более шире, чем «Не надо делать автоматическое удаление приветствий».

Comment: Мне кажется, автоматическое удаление во многих случаях сделает текст вопроса еще более "кривым", чем он был изначально. Все равно его придется править, делать нормальным с т.з. русского языка.

Comment: @avp приводите примеры, пожалуйста. Не надо продолжать традицию ультимативных заявлений из тела вопроса.

Comment: Так все зависит от того, какая регулярка. Русский язык, к сожалению, куда богаче английского. Если хватит воли создать километровую регулярку, которая корректно будет вырезать вещи типа "Приветствую вас, уважаемые знатоки", то нет вопросов. А если она будет превращать это в "вас, уважаемые знатоки", заставляя думать что курил автор, (и вопрос все равно придется править вручную), тогда какой смысл?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight безусловно, результат будет зависеть от качества регулярки, но и от грамотности автора тоже. Например, если в конце предложений не будет точек или, скажем, слово будет написано с ошибкой, на выходе может получиться несколько не то, что хотели. Но даже Ваш случай со знатоками всего лишь приведет к более быстрой правке вручную, нежели это было бы без автоудаления, то есть профит всё равно на лицо. Сначала нужно что-то реализовать, а потом уже смотреть как оно справляется с имеющимися сообщениями.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Чего додумывать и отказываться раньше времени, надо проверить и посмотреть на результаты. А учитывая, что фишка уже работает на enSO, значит более менее функция обкатана, и серьёзных сбоев быть не должно.

Comment: Возможно стоит пойти путём не подгоняние под недостатки движка, а исправлением их. Например сделать так что бы подняите шло только после изменений больше + 50 символов например.

Answer (score -5):

Вот пример текста, где я бы не хотел видеть автоматическое удаление приветствия. Реально приятно читать текст, автор доброжелательно относится к читателям.
Если же такое приветствие удалить, то текст будет уже не тот.
Мне скорее всего будет приятно общаться с таким автором, и возникает желание ему помочь. Если приветствие вырезать, то у меня не будет этой информации.

@Qwertiy писал, что при негативном приветствии сразу может быть видно кому не стоит отвечать (пересказ моими словами).

[ASP.Net WebAPI + winforms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767238/asp-net-webapi-winforms)

Привожу сюда текст оригинала, на случай если поправят сообщение.

> Всем доброго времени суток. Есть задание, создать набор приложений для
>   парсинг лог файла. Суть заключается в том что бы парсить лог файл по
>   определенным полям и сохранять результат в базу данных(допустим MS
>   SQL),набор полученных в результате парсинга данных расширить полем
>   Геолокации и при помощи доступных онлайн сервисов заполнить его
>   страной клиента. Само приложение парсера выполняется как отдельный
>   проект в winforms , а приложение для отображения результата парсинга в
>   формате JSON - asp.net webAPI с набором роутов.
>
> Сам файл мне распарсить вроде бы удалось через file.readline и splitы.
>   Правда у разных запросов бывает разное кол во частей , я это попытался
>   устранить с помощью switch(проверяя длинну массива , тоесть каждой
>   разбитой строки). Вопрос это вообще нормальный вариант и решение
>   задачи для такого? Слышал что можно использовать regexpы но в них я
>   очень туго разбираюсь, и не знаю какой вариант для парсинга будет
>   более правильным. А вот основные вопросы: 1. как расширять данных с
>   помощью поля геолокации? Откуда и как брать данные страны? В запросах
>   лога есть или имя хоста или ip адрес. Перерыл очень много гугла но
>   дельного так ничего не нашел. 2. Так как у меня опыта с самим asp.net
>   webAPI маловато, я не понял что значит набор приложений, asp +
>   winforms. Вот у меня есть приложение на winforms и там открываю файл
>   парсю его и сохраняю в бд(без геолокации пока), вот , а как дальше , я
>   так понял нужно создать еще проект asp и в нем подключить пространство
>   имен по winforms что бы был доступ к бд, или как то их еще можно по
>   человечески соединить?
>
> Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А теперь посмотрите на сгенерированный предпросмотр текста вопроса (для результатов поиска или списков вопросов метки), и какова его информативность с приветствием и без приветствия. Впрочем, у вопроса по ссылке слишком много  проблем и без приветствия.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight да, для предпросмотра это минус, согласен. Можно регуляторку применять для текста меток и description виджета поисковиков.

Comment: "уже не тот" и "будет приятно" не имеет ничего общего с чем-либо объективно полезным. Если вам неприятно отсутствие приветствий - это ваши личные проблемы, и приветствия на ruSO от этого нужными не становятся

Comment: @andreymal нет, вы меня неправильно поняли, мне не отсутствие приветствий неприятно, мне приятно их присутствие там где они уместны. И собственно тут всё просто, автор их написал, очевидно потому что счёл это нужным и полезным. Мне это понравилось, для меня это тоже нужно и полезно, очевидно таких людей ещё много. Говорить что это неполезно бессмыслено, так как факты говорят уже о другом. Но я вообще не вижу смысла спорить, если вам не нравится просто не читайте и не пишите, это ваше право. Те же кому это полезно и нужно пусть тоже пишут - это их право.

Comment: @andreymal я например в Питоне не разбираюсь и вопросы по питону на SO мне не интересны. Но это же не означает что теперь вопросы по Питону надо удалить с сайта? Мы все разные, у каждого свои вкусы, предпочтения. Мне кажется важно научиться принимать чужое мнение и уважать его даже если с ваших позиций это выглядит по-другому. Рыбам нужна вода что бы дышать, а людям воздух.

Comment: Это не факты, а ваши личные хотелки. Наличие или отсутствие приветствий не должно влиять на желание отвечать на вопрос, вам нужно перевоспитывать себя :)

Comment: Вопросы по питону вы можете "удалить", отправив метку в игнорируемые ;)

Comment: Здравствуйте! Доброго времени суток и приятного чтения! *"Реально приятно читать текст, автор доброжелательно относится к читателям."* - Так давайте лепить приветствия на все сообщения автоматом! Отвечаемость повысится!

Comment: важно понимать, что это не сайт для сочинений, одно из правил so - *вопрос-ответ, ничего лишнего*. Вы либо хотите и можете помочь либо не хотите и/или не можете. Что касается доброжелательности, то она должна быть выражена в желании получить ответ, а именно в предоставлении пояснений по вопросу при необходимости, в принятии ответа, голосовании за полезный ответ, а не в виде приветствий.