# Привет или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё, приветствия, шаблонные-комментарии, несущественные-правки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/57198

Собственно, надоело. Что всем делать нечего, только приветствия удалять и писать комментарий? К тому же, в чате уже обсуждалось, что комментарий писать не надо.

Comment: в чате кстати не видели, что комментарии писать не нужно, возможно подобные информационные сообщения в чате стоит рассылать всем пользователям, чтобы потом не было новых споров и недоумений?

Comment: нет. не привет. Насчет комментариев - человек прочитает один раз и больше не будет "приветкать", ничего страшного.

Comment: «Привет! Сегодня дождь и скверно. А мы не виделись, наверно, сто лет...» :)

Answer (score 17):

В вопросе [Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/) озвучен консенсус с enSO, и он включает коммент:

> Если привилегии редактирования без проверки ещё нет, то вычисткой *исключительно* избыточного текста (без прочих исправлений) лучше не заниматься.

[Оригинал:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions#comment43804_260778)

> I would not recommend making these changes as the *only* changes in a suggested edit (as the OP's rep would require.) If you have full editing privileges, that's different.

Это текущий консенсус на мете (как я его вижу), так что все правки, состоящие из *исключительно* "удалил приветствие" можно смело заворачивать.

---

Мое мнение: правка вопроса или ответа должна, по возможности, решать все проблемы форматирования, читабельности, опечаток. А не ограничиваться исправлением одной мелкой проблемы при игнорировании остальных.

[Правка того же вопроса от @alexander barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/486793/revisions) - отлично показывает разницу между "привести в порядок" и "вырезать приветствие". Пусть он и закрыл потом этот вопрос как дубликат :)

Comment: кстати да, в нашей правке было вырезано лишь приветствие и спасибо, остальные ошибки орфографии была не замечены. Однако отметим, что в очереди проверок правок есть возможность улучшить предлагаемую правку. Поэтому можно было не отклонять, а улучшить правку исправив все ошибки.

Comment: у @alexander barakin 90% правок заключаются только в вырезании приветствий

Comment: Может что то не так понял, но вроде там самый заплюсованный и отмеченный галкой "Yes, absolutely remove such things.", а вы приводите один из комментариев, в качестве "консенсуса".

Comment: @VladimirGamalian дело в том, что "Yes, absolutely remove such things." - это ответ на вопрос ["стоит ли удалять приветствия"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/) - да, стоит. А я отвечал на "стоит *предлагать правки*, состоящие толко из удаления приветствий, и при этом оставлять все остальные проблемы в посте нетронутыми" - нет, не стоит.

Comment: @etki у него есть привилегия делать это минуя очередь проверок

Answer (score 10):

Только, что обратили внимание, что это наша правка, поэтому собственно вот объяснение:

Разделы на se созданы для одной цели,- **получить ответ на интересующий вопрос в рамках тематики раздела se**.

Это подразумевает конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос **и все**.

Не нужно писать "*спасибо*", не нужно писать "*здравствуйте, привет, я начинающий кодер, помогите, не понимаю*" и иной мусор, - Вам и так помогут, если будет польза от Вашего вопроса и будет видно Ваше стремление самому разобраться.

Что же касается фразы "*Здравствуйте, может кто... Спасибо.*" - зачем писать фразы не относящиеся к вопросу? Если Вы думаете, что если Вы напишите "*Здравствуйте*", то это как-то повлияет на отношение к желанию помочь, то это скорее заблуждение, чем реальность.

Если Вы хотите показать свою воспитанность и благодарность, то, проголосуйте ЗА ответ и отметьте решением подходящий ответ, в крайнем случае(если Вы не можете удержаться от слов благодарности) напишите комментарий, "*спасибо Вам за помощь*" и удалите его через сутки(последнее конечно же не рекомендуется делать).

Разумеется, можно сказать, мы на ru.so трактуем свои правила, **быть** "*привет*" и пр. мусору. Но не кажется ли Вам, что в последствие это приведет к вопросу - "*а почему нельзя написать 20 строк о своей жизни и одну строчку по делу в тексте вопроса ?*" ?

Если более менее кратко, то тема данная уже поднималась на мете и на ru и на en. И результаты общественного мнения отражены в виде голосов ЗА и ПРОТИВ. Все, что можно было бы сказать, там уже было озвучено. На наш взгляд, 
слова приветствия есть ненужный мусор в вопросах, который со временем может привести к еще большему мусору в Q/A.

P.S.: таково наше мнение и Вы вполне можете как согласиться с ним, так и не согласиться - здесь свободное общество, никто никому ничего не обязан)

Comment: А комментарии насчет придерживайтесь правил приветствия и бесполезный ап вопроса - это не больший мусор? Человек пытается быть вежливым, а его за это попрекают правилами. Выглядит глупо на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Darth нет, это не мусор, это правка, в результате которой Q/A будут отображаться и индексироваться без постороннего мусора. Не можем отвечать за других, но свои комментарии в виде "придерживайтесь правил приветствия" мы удаляем спустя некоторое время и видим, что так же поступают и другие. Поэтому не можем с Вами согласиться.

Comment: а вы от чьего лица говорите? Вы император? Комментарии вы удаляете, когда автор вопроса уже получил свою порцию мусора вместо нужной ему помощи.

Comment: @Darth а Вы сами не пишите мусор, задавая не относящийся к делу вопрос?)) В комментарии есть ссылка на мету, смысл в том, чтобы показать пользователю **один раз** данную информацию, что обычно и бывает. По просмотрам,- опять таки не можем согласиться, т.к. если править после какого-либо числа просмотров, то вопрос попадет в верх очереди, что не есть хорошо. Разумеется не стоить делать 100 правок одну за другой, нужно стараться одной правкой максимально улучшить вопрос/ответ, а не только удалить ненужные фразы.

Comment: Просто немного странно выглядит когда человек о себе во множественном числе говорит.  Я перенес свой комментарий в ответ.

Comment: @Darth возможно также будет не лишним опубликовать Ваше мнение [в теме обсуждения приветствий, просьб и т.п.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/)

Comment: Кто такие "вы"? Я вижу комментарий от одного человека...

Comment: @PavelMayorov собственно вы уже ответили на свой вопрос

Answer (score -2):

Предлагаю делать подобные правки только для вопросов, которые собирают больше какого-то числа просмотров, например 100. 
Подавляющее же большинство вопросов - единоразовые, обычно в них заходят несколько десятков раз, пока они висят в топе неотвеченными. 
Поискового трафика нет, т.к. вопрос либо связан с ошибкой в конкретном коде, либо с непониманием автором, что он вообще накопипастил, либо с неумением гуглить. Например по тегу javascript ежедневно задается один и тот же по сути вопрос про замыкания в разных вариациях. В подобных вопросах поведение модераторов заставляет вспомнить выражение "синдром вахтера"