# Какая информация является несущественной?

Tags: обсуждение, правки, несущественные-правки

И вообще, что делать с такими [недоправками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/489480/revisions) (версия номер 2)?

Во-первых, на мой взгляд, стилистику из вопроса вычищать было неправильно. Единственное полезное исправление - замена инлайнового кода на цитату. Надо было блок кода подвинуть, но это не сделано.

Comment: У нас тут спор разгорелся с новой силой. Присоединяйтесь. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тут - это где?

Comment: Под ответом ниже.

Answer (score 11):

**что делать с такими недоправками?**

На мой взгляд, правка вполне корректная и самодостаточная. Осталось ещё место для улучшения, но редактор не обязан исправлять полностью все недостатки, особенно в новом вопросе или ответе и когда его правка не проходит проверку.

**Надо было блок кода подвинуть, но это не сделано.**

Вы ведь тоже этого не сделали :)

**Какая информация является несущественной?**

Например вот эта:

> Появилась такая проблема.

Разумеется, мы понимаем, что у автора появилась проблема. Иначе он не задавал бы вопрос. Почти наверняка эта проблема именно *такая*, как описано дальше в вопросе. Было бы странно, если бы дальше он писал о *другой* проблеме.

> Может кто подсказать что я делаю не так?

Да, конечно. Пара сотен участников сайта сможет подсказать. Вы удовлетворены ответом?

Цитирую Эрика Реймонда:

> **Избегайте бессмысленных просьб**
>
> Не поддавайтесь соблазну завершить свой запрос бессмысленными вопросами вида: "Не поможет ли мне кто-нибудь?" или "Есть ли вообще ответ?" Во-первых, если вы хоть сколько-нибудь компетентно описали свою проблему, подобные дополнительные вопросы, как минимум, излишни. Во-вторых, поскольку они излишни, хакерам они кажутся надоедливыми — и в ответ их так и подбивает написать логически безукоризненную отписку типа: "Да, помочь вам можно" или "Нет, вам уже ничем не поможешь".
>
> В общем случае, вопросы с ответами да-нет лучше не задавать, если только вы не хотите получить ответ да-или-нет.

На первый взгляд это может показаться незначительным. **Но я считаю очень важным приучать начинающих разработчиков формулировать свои мысли четко, полно, но без избыточных конструкций.** Например мои коллеги-разработчики наверняка не оценят, если в трекере задач я напишу «у нас есть проблема» (тип задачи явно на это указывает) или «можете ли вы это исправить?» (нет, мы тут приходим кофе пить).

Comment: Мне кажется, Эрик немного эпатирует. Мы не машины, и общаемся по-другому. Формально незначащие клаузы в тексте служат индикаторами вежливости и другими социальными знаками, которые важны для homo sapiens. Пример: «[пока не смог найти или нагуглить, как](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478736/10105)» — этот текст ничего не прибавляет к вопросу, но он говорит «я не паразитирую на вас, я потратил своё время на поиски ответа, ответ не лежит на поверхности, вопрос не тривиальный». Мне кажется, что такие вещи важны.

Comment: @VladD, такие «вещи» важны в общении, несомненно. но, по-моему, излишни в *базе знаний*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Я не считаю, что у нас тут строго говоря _база знаний_. Раз знания добавляют живые люди на добровольной основе, почему бы не потрафить их человеческим слабостям? Я, например, последовательно не отвечаю на вопросы (даже если знаю ответ), в которых текст вопроса дан невежливо, в императиве («Написать программу, которая будет рассчитывать X исходя из Y. Использовать Z.») — хотя, возможно, _содержание_ вопроса полностью корректно. Убирание _человечности_ из вопроса на мой взгляд является _ухудшением_ вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: P. S.: Разумеется, в известных пределах. Длинные истории слушать тоже не всегда интересно. Не говоря уже о мольбах и самоунижении.

Comment: @VladD, императив (в вопросах) неуместен и в базе знаний. которую мы (надеюсь) строим. лирические отступления и многословие важны для худ. литературы, допустимы в живом общении (хотя и вызывают зевоту), но излишни в литературе технической. в *базе знаний* же они **затрудняют** пользование этой самой *базой знаний*. я думаю, что затруднять использование накопленных знаний, намеренно оставляя «лирику» — просто не стоит.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Мне не кажется, например, что в формате реальной базы знаний уместны вопросы наподобие «у меня ошибка, вот код, как исправить?» Потому что база знаний — это ответы на вопрос «как делать», а не «почему данный код неправильный». Вопросы типа «почему» и «как» в формат базы знаний вписываются, а вот вопросы «почему вылетает» (которых у нас тут очень много) — нет. Именно поэтому я не думаю, что у нас тут строго говоря формат базы знаний. Мне кажется, наш формат шире.

Comment: @VladD «почему …» — отличный вопрос для базы знаний, как мне кажется. согласен с тем, что «наш формат шире» — в процессе накопления знаний есть ещё и фаза «конкретный человек получает ответ на свой вопрос». но это не основная задача, а «приятный довесок»: не один, а гораздо больше людей впоследствии смогут извлечь пользу из этого вопроса-ответа. вот ради этих людей и не стоит намеренно оставлять «лирику».

Comment: Я сомневаюсь в полезности данного ответа. Если вам чуждо человеческое отношение и общение, если вам тяжело даются разговоры не по делу, небольшие интро в вопросах вида `Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой:`, то зачем вам любое сообщество, не только `ruSO`? Зачем вам коллеги, друзья, семья?
 Зачем вам общество, в принципе? Сидите дома, никуда не ходите, ни с кем не говорите, общайтесь только с компьютером. Судя по ответу - то, что надо для вас!

Comment: @KitScribe лично мне сообщество нужно, чтобы делиться знаниями, а не эмоциями

Comment: @KitScribe тут формат энциклопедии. Вы видели где-нибудь в разделе FAQ например банка, предисловие в вопросе "Привет, доброго времени суток, карта заблокирована, что делать?"

Comment: @KitScribe я стараюсь улучшать соотношение сигнал/шум. Больше сути, меньше «шелухи». Время экспертов ценно, даже когда они его «дарят», отвечая на сайте. Так пускай они не тратят его на выуживание смысла из витиеватых конструкций, на разбор стены текста без абзацев и знаков препинания, на разбор стены кода без пояснений.

Comment: @KitScribe потому что это совершенно бесполезная информация. Как вы из этого сделали вывод об отказе от общения, мне неведомо. Скажем, мне лично не нравится, когда мне присылают сообщение "можно вопрос?" и ждут ответа вместо того, чтобы сразу прислать сам вопрос и получить либо сразу ответ на него, либо мой отказ. Можно понять, когда это делают лично, голосом, т. к. собеседнику надо отвлечься. Но в текстовых коммуникациях это неуместно. Так и здесь: здесь не форум, нормы отличаются от форумных. Никто не найдёт вопрос по приветствию или "вежливым обёрткам", его найдут по описанию проблемы.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian боюсь, вы немного путаете. На `ruSO`, как и везде на `StackExchange` спрашивают **люди** у **людей**. Так что это скорее `call-центр`, нежели `FAQ`, если уж и делать такое сравнение

Comment: @KitScribe сайт вопросов и ответов — это самая настоящая документация, причём в одной из лучших форм документации. А колл-центры каждую проблему решают заново. Мы точно не колл-центр. И активные участники по квалификации очень сильно выше, чем средний контингент колл-центра.

Comment: @D-side я не говорю, что я поддерживаю тупость. Напротив я её не одобряю. Автор описал ситуацию так, что для себя я сделал вывод, что он ведёт себя, как машина и уважительное отношение и минимальные нормы дружелюбия ему чужды. Напомню, что **в справке советуют быть дружелюбными**

Comment: @NickVolynkin это был пример, чтобы объяснить мою точку зрения, что уважительное отношение и дружелюбие имеют место быть, если вопрос не полон камбэков, рассуждений автора не по теме и т.д.

Comment: @KitScribe "минимальные нормы дружелюбия" штука субъективная. Минимум может быть отсутствием явных проявлений неуважения, например. И в вопросе, заданном прямо, без обиняков, извинений, приветствий и художественных оборотов просто нет места неуважению. Если, конечно, сама суть вопроса не выдаёт вопиющую наглость автора и неуважение ко времени отвечающих :]

Comment: @D-side похоже, всё же, что тут большинство пользователей машины :|

Comment: @KitScribe для меня «минимальные нормы дружелюбия» — это когда человек пишет внятно и осмысленно, когда в тексте есть структура (порядок). Тогда я вижу, что автор подумал о читателе, что он позаботился, чтобы мне было понятно и просто читать. Другими словами, мне важны действия, вложенный в вопрос труд. А вежливая конструкция не добавит дружелюбия в шизофазический поток мыслей.

Comment: @KitScribe, нет (про "тут большинство пользователей машины :|"), это большинство активистов такое. Остальные, как обычные (достаточно ленивые) люди.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а если вопрос нормально построен, ну отлично в нём всё... Но!  Он содержит в себе приветствие. Что тогда? Удалить такой вопрос? Минус влепить? Какой плохой автор, поздоровался со мной! Я тут, между прочим не ваши приветствия читать прихожу, а базу знаний заполнять! По приветствию на вопрос - это от минус секунды до минус двух секунд. Если бы приветствий не было, я бы мог ответить ещё на целых 2 вопроса в день! :D

Comment: @KitScribe вы напрасно считаете участников сайта целевой аудиторией. Целевая аудитория - это пользователи, приходящие из поисковиков. Именно так происходят 94.8% посещений сайта. И им совсем не интересно смотреть на приветствия, обращенные не к ним.

Comment: @KitScribe никаких минусов, закрытий и удаления. Нынешний консенсус: имея 2000+ репутации, можно приветствие смело отпилить от вопроса правкой. Если нет, либо предложить правку с выпиливанием в составе других улучшений, либо не трогать -- это не настолько значительное изменение, чтобы отправлять проверяемую правку.

Comment: @KitScribe [Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93)

Comment: @KitScribe, +1 :)

Comment: @Nofate я не говорю, что вопросы вида `"Я тут ел за компом и случайно стёр копипаст алгоритма фиббоначи и не могу его найти. Кто может подсказать линейное решение?"` хороши. Я про то, что **быть дружелюбным**, **здороваться**, **сообщать, что человек не перекладывает работу на тебя, а сам пытался уже что-то делать**, **умело шутить** - **это всё нормально** и **судя по справке приветствуется**. А **если нет - удалите к чертям эти пункты и не вводите в заблуждение никого**. **Перепишите справку и напишите, что нужно вести себя, как машины**, что **именно такое поведение** норма для `ruSO`

Comment: @PavelMayorov откуда вы можете знать что человеку интересно, а что - нет, на что человек может закрыть глаза, а на что - нет? Откуда вы можете знать что человека раздражает, а что - нет? Если вам неинтересно - то так и говорите. А мне вот гораздо приятнее отвечать на вопросы тем, кто показывает, что он в первую очередь человек, гораздо приятнее видеть вопросы, авторы которых проявляют уважение к людям. И так было ещё до регистрации на `ruSO`. **Мы все разные**, и **своя шкура смотрится хорошо на ком-либо в любой ситуации только для владельца шкуры**. Это называется эгоизм

Comment: @KitScribe так в итоге что, получается вы хотите всем навязать свою точку зрения и чтобы сделали так, как приятно будет лично **вам**?) ну хочется отвечать на определенно выделенные вами вопросы - ок. чего вы тут распинаетесь — непонятно

Comment: @KitScribe `Я про то, что быть дружелюбным, здороваться, сообщать, что человек не перекладывает работу на тебя, а сам пытался уже что-то делать, умело шутить - это всё нормально и судя по справке приветствуется.` - где это такое написано?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), например, в разделе "Будьте дружелюбными" про юмор

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) про то, что надо сообщать, что ты не балду гонял, а пытался решить проблему

Comment: @KitScribe не вижу ни слова про *умело шутить - это всё нормально и  приветствуется.*.

Comment: @KitScribe `тут про то, что надо сообщать` - нет там слова **надо**, там есть  **советы**, *позволяющих увеличить шансы на получение ответа*

Comment: @KitScribe у вас явные проблемы с интерпретацией текста.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в понятие "дружелюбия" на мой взгляд вложено и приветствие. А по поводу вашего первого комментария - **я не пытаюсь никому это навязать. Наоборот, я всего лишь высказался, что я не согласен, и на меня накинулись**. Я ничего не навязываю, ведите себя как хотите, мне плевать. **Это я защищаюсь от внешней агрессии и навязывания. Я пытаюсь объяснить свою позицию, отстаиваю её, но не навязываю.** Повторяю: **мне наплевать на то, как вы себя ведёте, мне наплевать на вас**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет у меня проблем с интерпретацией текста. Я вставил неправильное слово: вставил **надо**, а нужно было вставить **можно**. А насчёт юмора: **там и не написано, что это не приветствуется**. Иными словами, **без внятного ТЗ результат ХЗ**. Вот и под `не забывайте про юмор` я понял, что хорошо пошутить - приветствуется. Да и кто откажется, в принципе, от хорошей шутки? Разве что только **бесчувственная машина-полемист, которая пытается навязать свою точку зрения и выиграть выдуманный спор...**

Comment: @KitScribe я защищаюсь от внешней агрессии и поэтому срусь со всеми и яростно плюю на вас и не могу остановится вовремя?....... Г - логика.........`в понятие "дружелюбия" на мой взгляд вложено и приветствие` - то есть если я скажу "Добрый день!" и врежу вам по лицу - это считается дружелюбностью? Смех да и только.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы уже изрядно достали меня **всей толпой**, вот нервы и начали сдавать. Не всегда удаётся держать себя в руках, когда тебя др##ат на одну и ту же тему, пытаясь доказать, что ты неправ. Хотя я ни спор не начинал, ни утверждение против не высказывал. **Я всего лишь высказал свою точку зрения, с которой вы, как и все, кому она не нравится, можете молча не согласиться, если вам что-то не нравится**. __*P.S.*__ Если вас удивляет, что мне на вас плевать, рекомендую обратиться к специалисту с целью подлечить уровень собственного величия

Comment: @KitScribe ты смешон

Comment: @АлексейШиманский думайте как хотите, это ваше право, и я у вас его не отбираю. Но учитывайте, что **это вам и всем, кто пытался меня переубедить, есть дело до того, что вашу точку зрения не разделяют**. Не мне... А значит у вас проблемы психологического характера. Дабы не задеть вас и кого бы то ни было, список потенциальных источников озвучивать не буду, но задуматься советую

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [ваш лучший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603544/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2-layermask-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82-1-layer/603545#603545) - вы же пошутили! Как вы могли?! А ещё вы воду в начале разводите! Как посмели?! А смайлики?!!!! 
Но на самом деле ответ хороший, и я дал плюса. К чему это? Не пойму я вашего наезда, если вы сами шутите и делаете лирически-сентиментальные интро.