# «информационный мусор» — помогает или мешает пользоваться базой знаний?

Tags: обсуждение, правила, стиль

поводом к написанию вопроса послужила [дискуссия в комментариях под этим ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2479/178576).

причиной же является отношение к «оправдательным фразам» в частности, и к прочим «политесам» вообще.

---

нередко в вопросах новичков ([и не только](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478736/10105)) можно встретить фразы типа «[пробовал всё, но ничего не получилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/200763/178576)», «[искал везде, но ничего не нашёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/204871/178576)», «[ничего не понял](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470899/178576)», «[заранее большое спасибо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491263/178576)» и так далее и тому подобное.

---

**помогает ли** наличие таких фраз пользоваться базой знаний [тем, кто приходит из поисковиков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/685/178576), или мешает?

а может быть, мы уже и не строим «[город знаний](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1146/178576)» на этом сайте? (этот вопрос — риторический)

---

**уточнение ввиду недопонимания в первом же ответе**:

вопрос «помогает или мешает» относится не к задающим вопрос и не к отвечающим на него, а к *пользователям базы знаний*, которых, по-моему, на порядки больше первых двух перечисленных категорий.

---

По результатам обсуждения может потребоваться внести изменения в раздел справки: [Улучшение перевода «Какое поведение ожидается от участников?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2492/181472)

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните, почему наличие таких фраз будет той преградой, которая не позволит нам выполнить задуманное?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky,  это уже совсем другой вопрос. вероятно, я «переборщил» с упоминаниями «города знаний», но сделал это лишь с целью придать вопросу больше «трагизма». собственно интересующий меня вопрос выделен жирным шрифтом. // я внёс поправки.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вежливые уточнения наподобие «искал в гугле, не нашёл», «пробовал ещё добавить звёздочку, компилятор почему-то ругается», «обыскал последний драфт стандарта, не нашёл нормативную ссылку» поясняют по сути, на каком уровне находятся знания ТС, и на каком уровне нужно давать ответ. Поэтому к их удалению я бы относился с осторожностью.

Comment: @VladD, угу, получается [дилемма](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2520/#comment7890_2523), включающая и ваше уточнение.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Мне, кстати, в общем и целом нравится вот этот текст: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html. Гляньте раздел «[Хорошие и плохие вопросы](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#examples)». Там как раз о случаях полезной (хотя вроде бы и излишней) информации.

Comment: @VladD А как повлияет на ответ, искал человек в гугле или нет, например? Добавление звездочки это доп.инфо, такое убирать не надо.

Comment: @VladD, так всё-таки *эрик не эпатирует*? // серьёзно: как мне представляется, там изложены рекомендации, в нашем случае применимые лишь к фазе «задают вопрос и дают ответ(ы)». но не к фазе «вопрос и ответ пополняют базу знаний».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Эпатирует, конечно. Но в его эпатаже есть доля истины.

Comment: @KromStern: Ну, вот вам пример: одно дело вопрос (по C#) «какие ограничения на параметры у конструктора string из char и int» (напрашивается комментарий «ну загляни в MSDN, что, разучился читать?»), другое дело «какие ограничения на параметры у конструктора string из char и int, в MSDN (следует ссылка на статью из документации) эта секция пропущена». Это конечно не полный аналог гугла, но где-то рядом: стандартное место, где по идее обязан быть ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Эрик описывает, как будет думать специалист, читая вопрос. Для того, кто хочет получить ответ, это должно быть важно.

Comment: @VladD, «какие ограничения…» — по-моему, оба варианта несут одинаковое количество информации с точки зрения базы знаний. но, возможно, излишняя информация имеет определённый смысл **для отвечающего**.

Comment: @VladD Вы опять привели уточняющую информацию, важную для вопроса и ответа, а не пример "дефолтного" мусора )

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: С точки зрения базы знаний — безусловно. С другой стороны, на вопрос-то должны отвечать живые люди.

Comment: @VladD, *Для того, кто хочет получить ответ, это должно быть важно* — да, вполне возможно. но для базы знаний это не несёт полезной информации. я уже написал вам про дилемму.

Comment: @KromStern: Это да. Но я просто хотел привести пример того, что грань между мусором и важной информацией довольно тонкая, и не стоит её проводить лишь на основании формальных признаков.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Ну вот это мы как раз и обсуждаем: **кто** адресат вопроса?

Comment: @VladD, на первой фазе — отвечающие, на второй (гораздо более многочисленной) — ищущие ответ на *свой* вопрос.

Comment: *грань между мусором и важной информацией довольно тонкая, и не стоит её проводить лишь на основании формальных признаков* — а вот, кстати, не напрасно существует награда за правку вопроса, на который даёшь ответ. дал ответ — привёл вопрос к виду, подобающему базе знаний. по-моему, логично.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Именно так. Но если мы советуем ориентироваться на вторую группу адресатов, это, возможно, уменьшает шансы на получение ответа на _первой_ фазе.

Comment: @VladD, ещё раз напомню про дилемму, на которую уже обратил ваше внимание выше.

Answer (score 11):

> ## Кратко
>
> Stack Overflow – база *прикладных решений*. Вопрос и ответ пишутся один раз, а читаются многократно. Следует оптимизировать все содержимое сайта для чтения.

С другой стороны, мы не роботы и часто подобные фразы могут быть частью сообщения.

1. *Если вводная фраза делает вопрос понятней или добавляет контекст.* Иногда, без вводных фраз идея предложения может быть воспринята двояко. Мы все уникальны, без вводных конструкций кто-то может понять вопрос или ответ по–другому.
2. *Общие стандарты и нормы.* Иногда подобных фраз требуют нормы культуры. Например, без вводных фраз автор вопроса может показаться другим (и, что более важно, чувствовать себя) грубым. После решения задачи, таки вводные конструкции, конечно же, можно вырезать, но они могут быть жизненно необходимы для участвующих в процессе решении вопроса.
3. *Личный стиль изложения.* Люди зачастую имеют свой стиль изложения. Им попросту сложно или даже невозможно выражаться по другому.

На Stack Overflow мы делаем упор на кристаллизацию знаний. В теории, все не относящиеся к вопросу или ответу должно быть опущено. К сожалению, это не всегда возможно, особенно, на первых этапах участия в сообществе. Следует также учесть огромную разницу между модерацией и публикацией. Я сам ни раз испытывал волнение при публикации как вопросов, так и ответов, что добавляло «лишних слов» в сообщение. Модерирую же я с холодной головой, так как являюсь третей стороной. Опыт использования сайта в этих случая различается кардинально.

База знаний требует поддержки. Нет ничего страшного, в том что сообщество в последствии удаляет все не относящееся к вопросу или ответу, как и в стремлении авторов добавить, теоретически, не нужные вводные конструкции, которые можно было бы опустить. Но всегда необходимо помнить о том, что улучшая читаемость сообщений путь даже на несколько секунд, мы экономим часы жизни реальных людей, которые они смогут потрать на что-то более полезное обществу.

Comment: получается дилемма: с одной стороны, «приводить вопрос в порядок, достойный базы знаний» следует прямо в очереди первых сообщений. с другой — читая вопрос без «реверансов« (и даже, возможно, самоуничижения), некоторые люди, способные дать ответ, могут и обидеться на «сухость».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Мне кажется, можно судить по ситуации. Если в вопросе достаточно кода, то он понятен без слов вообще.

Comment: не следует игнорировать стадию, когда автор вопроса в ответ на комментарии уточняет/проясняет вопрос: *на этой стадии* любые сигналы в тексте, которые указывают на готовность автора вопроса учитывать обратную связь, являются важными. Удаление текста, который не нужен в **конечной** удовлетворительной версии вопроса, может препятствовать превращению "плохого вопроса с адекватным автором" в "приемлемый вопрос для базы знаний" т.к. удаление текста может исказить впечатление об авторе вопроса. Содержимое сайта создаётся в основном добровольцами -- нельзя игнорировать человеческие отношения.

Answer (score 10):

Доброго всем времени суток многоуважаемые форумчане! В гугле пробовал искать, но ничего не нашёл - вот пишу тут. В яндексе кстати тоже, не удалось найти информации.

Это мой ответ. Я постараюсь ответить на поставленный вопрос как умею, если получится, но даже если не получится то все равно попытаюсь.

Заранее благодарю вас, что вы обратили внимание на мой ответ и прошу сильно не пинать и не ставить минусов. Это очень важно для меня, потому что я только начал изучать программирование на языках Java, C#, PHP, Pyhton и Java Script. Мне сказали, что это хорошие языки, и как настоящий ученик прислушался к совету.

Сравните сами, какие-то сухие слова условия, и, витиеватое течение мысли автора, приветствующее вас, рассказывающего про свою жизнь и тернистый путь к формулировке условия. Казалось бы мелочь, ан нет, не так все просто!

**Конечно же информационный мусор помогает!**

Вроде бы описал все что хотел, но не стесняйтесь, спрашивайте, я постараюсь всем ответить на вопросы и уточнения. Огромное всем спасибо, что потратили толику своего драгоценного времени на чтение этого сообщения! Низкий вам поклон и три раза «ку!». Не минусуйте, пожалустааа!!! )

*Прошу каждого дополнить этот ответ ценным мусором, чтобы он не был так сух!*

И воздастся каждому по делам его. {Пс. 61:13; Мф. 16:27.}

Вова,
программист
начинающий и заканчивающий (без обид!)

Comment: Больше безумия! )

Comment: @NickVolynkin: научи дурака богу молиться, он себе лоб расшибёт. Что этот текст доказывает? Что любую идею можно извратить?
 Какое это имеет отношение к поведению реальных людей на Stack Overflow? Представление аргументов в такой форме как в этом ответе, я считаю не конструктивно, так как подобное поведение заразно -- не нужно Stack Overflow в lukomore
 превращать.

Comment: @jfs хотя этот ответ и не совем "чист" от полезных деталей, но вы его можете успешно сократить до 2 строк и он останется таким же как и был - (выделено жирным). Теперь инвертируем сарказм, и вуаля - вот наглядный ответ и пример, почему "мусор" не нужен.

Comment: Ваш ответ это всё равно что на вопрос: "полезна ли буква "А" в ответах на SO, ответить «АААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААА» — это бесполезный ответ, который ничего кроме того что можно злоупотребить чем угодно, не доказывает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov между прочим, Пихтон тут был специально. Я в каком-то вопросе видел такое написание. Кстати, оно всё ещё встречается: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pyhton

Comment: @NickVolynkin сарказм ответа про его никчемную объемность, а не безграмотность и опечатки, но если вы настаиваете, то пусть будет и Пихтон ))

Answer (score 6):

Лично я отношу эти вопросы к стилистике. На понимание сути вопроса они никак не влияют, поэтому в этом плане не важно, есть они или нет. Т. е. пришедшим почитать ответы всё равно, есть там какая-то фраза, или нет.

Но есть и другая сторона. То, как автор задаёт вопрос, показывает его отношение. Можно предсказать, как он поведёт себя при получении каких-то частичных ответов, нужна ли ему подсказка, в какую сторону копать, концептуальная инструкция с чего начать (например, если он уже профессионал, но впервые столкнулся с какой-то технологией или хочет попробовать что-то новое) или готовый код, который он сможет скопипастить в свой проект даже не меняя имена переменных. Будет ли автор отвечать на уточняющие вопросы, действительно ли ему нужно решение проблемы и т. д.

В общем, на мой взгляд, стилистические особенности следует оставлять, поскольку это важно для отвечающих.

> Если приветствия и реверансы повышают мотивацию к ответам, то почему бы не добавить их ко всем вопросам подряд? Давайте везде впишем, "искал в гугле и не смог найти" и "помогите кто-нибудь".

Они могут как повысить, так и понизить. Факт в том, что они влияют на восприятие и желание отвечать. Некоторых формулировок достаточно, чтобы я прошёл мимо, даже есть считаю, что мог бы ответить. Некоторые наоборот увеличивают симпатию к вопросу. С одной стороны, их убирание как бы уравнивает вопросы. С другой, это грабли для отвечающего - он просто не будет по очищенному вопросу ожидать ту реакцию, которую получит дальше. Возможность оценить вопрос, а также профессионализм и адекватность спрашивающего важны, не стоит везде раскидывать грабли.

> Вторую часть вашего комментария, "С другой, это грабли ..." не понял.

Такой пример. Есть новичок, который ничего не знает и задаёт какой-то примитивный вопрос. Этот вопрос кем-то чистится и он уже не выглядит так как раньше - его нельзя отличить от вопроса от того, кто просто впервые столкнулся с чем-то новым. Ты отвечаешь на этот вопрос, рассчитывая, что человек поймёт идею. А в результате получаешь коммент в духе "ой, я скопипастил твой кусок кода и оно ругается, что переменная не существует". Как раз [рассказывал](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316731/4928642) сейчас, что наличие уточняющих комментариев может снижать желание других пользователей отвечать. Наличие ответа - ещё значительнее.

Итак, ты только что дал ответ, который человеку не помог и понизил его шансы получить другие ответы. Что дальше? Есть два пути, либо бросить его в таком состоянии, что некрасиво, либо продолжать помогать, чего тебе делать не хочется.

Вот в этом и есть грабли - тебя завели в невыгодную ситуацию. Было бы гораздо лучше, если бы ты сразу оценил оригинальный вопрос и прошёл мимо. Но теперь уже поздно.

Comment: *стилистические особенности следует оставлять, поскольку это важно для отвечающих* — а какую пользу несёт эта информация для пользователей базы знаний? мой вопрос именно о них.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, первый абзац же. Для пользователей базы безразлично, для отвечающих полезно. Вывод: оставлять.

Comment: неужели «информационный мусор» не затрудняет понимание написанного? мне кажется, обладатели навыка мгновенного выделения существенной информации — всё-таки (увы) уникумы. представьте, что вы ищете ответ на вопрос, в котором «ничего не понимаете»: не помешает ли вам в понимании найденного «информационный мусор»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, лично мне - нет. К тому же, я ведь всё-таки ответ ищу, а не вопрос. Даже если у автора была несколько иная проблема, мне не надо выяснять, что именно у него было не так как у меня, мне надо выяснить, подходят ли мне ответы.

Comment: вы хотите сказать, что вообще не читаете вопросы, производя поиск нужной вам информации на любом из сайтов стиля q&a, даже когда суть вашего поиска лежит в малознакомой вам области? тогда — да. содержимое вопросов, действительно, не существенно. но, насколько я могу припомнить, при всех поисках, когда я попадал на один из сайтов стиля q&a, в первую очередь я читал именно вопрос, чтобы понять, «туда ли я попал», и стоит ли читать ответы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я читаю вопрос, хотя и не слишком внимательно. При этом перечисленные фразы в нём мне никак не мешают.

Answer (score 3):

из обсуждения выношу **дилемму**:

с **одной** стороны, «приводить вопрос в порядок, достойный базы знаний» следует прямо в очереди первых сообщений. с **другой** — читая вопрос без «реверансов» и избыточной (с точки зрения *пользователя базы знаний*) информации, некоторые люди, способные дать ответ, могут и обидеться на «чрезмерную сухость или нежелание воспользоваться поиском».

---

а ведь есть решение: дал ответ — убери из вопроса лишнюю информацию. кому как не отвечающему знать, что в вопросе существенно, а что — лишь «реверансы»?

за это и поощрительные знаки предусмотрены:

- [евангелист](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/90/explainer)
- [наставник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/91/refiner)
- [просветитель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/92/illuminator)

Comment: Я плохой врач, на все вопросы отвечаю "примите пурген", мне тоже удалять из вопросов все не относящееся по моему ответу? ;-)

Comment: @KromStern, для плохих врачей есть откат правки, а для совсем плохих — живительный пурген в виде бана.

Comment: В том и дело, что подача ответа не дает каких-то особых прав на редактирование вопроса и его подгонку под ответ.

Comment: @KromStern, а при чём здесь права? вносить предложения по исправлению могут даже анонимы.

Comment: Вы специально предлагаете тому кто дал ответ убирать из вопроса лишнюю информацию. Я считаю это не верным. Убирать реверансы следует всем. Дающему ответ не следует к тому же еще и убирать, то что по *его* мнению лишнее.

Comment: @KromStern *Убирать реверансы следует всем, а дающему ответ не следует к тому же еще и убирать, то что по его мнению лишнее* — обеими руками «за». но поступление ответа — это как раз тот переломный момент, когда вопрос/ответ (условно говоря) пополняют базу знаний. «реверансы» уже становятся не нужны. и лучший кандидат на их удаление — как раз отвечающий. а злоупотребления ведь легко отслеживаются в очереди предлагаемых правок — отвечающий, не набравший 2000 репутации, не минует чаши сей.

Comment: По реверансам мы согласны. Я против того чтобы отвечающему специально предлагалось править вопрос "под ответ". Ведь он вполне мог неправильно его понять или что-то пропустить. А так - он заметает следы, и только автор вопроса сможет сразу это заметить. Также представьте ситуацию когда дано 2 разных ответа - получится конфликт интересов/правок

Comment: @KromStern, если правка находится на проверке, другой пользователь (с <2000 репутации) не сможет внести исправлений. и даже анонимы могут посмотреть историю правок.

Comment: @KromStern *Я против того чтобы отвечающему специально предлагалось править вопрос "под ответ"* — надеюсь, до подобного извращения мы никогда не докатимся.

Comment: Ну, убирать реверансы выглядит как-то неадекватно тоже. Получается, сначала мы к участникам вежливо и чуть ли не подлизываемся, а потом, когда ответ уже дан, сразу меняем тон — ответил, чувак, ты нас больше не интересуешь.

Comment: @VladD, по-моему, ровно наоборот: «ответ есть, можно уже и не подлизываться к отвечающим». но довести до абсурда можно, конечно, всё, что угодно. предлагаю временами вспоминать, о чём был вопрос, и какие моменты затрагивались при обсуждении.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Ну, а этично ли это по отношению к отвечающему? (Помните анекдот — «не путайте туризм с эмиграцией»?)

Comment: @VladD, в вопросах типа «а этично ли сё и это, и то, что мы вообще создаём базу знаний» не считаю себя достаточно компетентным.

Answer (score 3):

Глупый спор. На StackOverflow приходят за ответами, а не за вопросами.
Например я, перейдя на SE из поисковика, из всей длинной страницы выбираю только небольшую часть: заголовок вопроса и первый ответ. Иногда встречаются вопросы, в которых первым показывается "принятый" ответ, у которого значительно меньше голосов, чем у второго. Тогда читаю и его. Если ни в первом ни во втором ответе нет подходящего решения, возвращаюсь в поисковик.
Вывод: если топикстартеру нечем больше заняться, пусть лучше ответы исправляет.

Comment: Часто нетоповые ответы тоже полезны. А в остальном согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Если приветствия и реверансы повышают мотивацию к ответам, то почему бы не добавить их ко всем вопросам подряд? Давайте везде впишем, "искал в гугле и не смог найти" и "помогите кто-нибудь".

В общем призываю всех вспомнить про то, что мы программисты и айтишники, и знаем что такое **DRY** и ценим это.

Comment: Они могут как повысить, так и понизить. Факт в том, что они влияют на восприятие и желание отвечать. Некоторых формулировок достаточно, чтобы я прошёл мимо, даже есть считаю, что мог бы ответить. Некоторые наоборот увеличивают симпатию к вопросу. С одной стороны, их убирание как бы уравнивает вопросы. С другой, это грабли для отвечающего - он просто не будет по очищенному вопросу ожидать ту реакцию, которую получит дальше. Возможность оценить вопрос, а также профессионализм и адекватность спрашивающего важны, не стоит везде раскидывать грабли.

Comment: @Qwertiy Значит я за уравнивание. Вторую часть вашего комментария, "С другой, это грабли ..." не понял.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ.