# Где бы почитать правила

Tags: поддержка, правила

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где возможно почитать текущую редакцию Правил? В одной из моих "правок" меня пригласили почитать [это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7). Там утверждения и обсуждения, интересно конечно, но ... где сами Правила? Где сухой остаток?

Comment: Не могу сказать точно, так как сам никакие правила на форумах не читаю, так как в любом случае на форумах, особенно как этот, творится произвол модераторов . Именно модераторы ведут себя по хамски. Тем не менее когда вы задаете вопрос нажав кнопу "Задать вопрос", в правой стороне экрана появляется текст, где уаазывается на некую справку.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help и там еще много ссылок. Внимательно просмотрите.

Answer (score 6):

[Официальная справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) вон там:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> Где сухой остаток?

**Обычно это *принятый* (с галочкой) ответ на Мете.** На Мете галочка обычно означает "итоговое решение", и оно не всегда имеет больше всего голосов (об этом позже). Это негласное правило, которое почему-то обычно соблюдают.

Правила это хорошо, но **консенсус сообщества выше правил**. Потому что важнее правил **идея** ресурса, а правила нужны лишь чтобы эта идея лучше воспринималась новыми участниками. Но правила, к сожалению, не идеальны, хотя и улучшаются со временем.

Если сообщество вырабатывает на Мете (здесь) аргументированную позицию по некоторому вопросу и укрепляет её большим количеством (и большинством) голосов, *изложенное в этой позиции считается действующим*. **Даже если противоречит Правилам**. Иногда согласно принятым решениям в Правила даже вносятся изменения.

**Но.** Выше консенсуса в некоторых случаях *решение администрации*. Эдакое "право вето". Ряд вещей, так уж сложилось, может реализовать только администрация, и если эти два фактора совпадают, сообщество всё равно ничего особо не может сделать. Происходит это нечасто, ведь в сообществе это порождает [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91) про [модераторский-произвол](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb) и прочие виды неудовольствия и несогласия.

Answer (score 1):

> где сами Правила?

В правилах. В правом верхнем углу перед поиском.

> Где сухой остаток?

А нету. Считается, что общественность согласна с вариантом, имеющим наибольшее число голосов.

PS: А этот вопрос следовало задавать на мете. Проголосовал за перенос.