# Убрать "Привет!" из справки!

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, приветствия

[Главная страница справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) содержит совершенно ненужный "Привет!":

> [image: Привет!]

Предлагаю его убрать оттуда раз и навсегда. Как это [делается](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/93/176217) для обычных сообщений.