# Как поблагодарить Stack Overflow пользователя за помощь в научной статье

Tags: обсуждение

Я задал вопрос, мне помогли. Если просто советом - достаточно спасибо, на мой взгляд. Но если помогли портянкой кода, который ускорил наше исследование, как минимум, на пару дней, то спасибо должно быть существенней. Я не говорю в данный момент про материальное вознаграждение, я говорю про авторство.
В моей ситуации, как учёного на 60%, благодарность обычно простая: в статье пишется стандартная фраза "Благодарим имярека за то и то". Мелочь, но приятно, и моя совесть чиста. (В определённых бюджетных организациях благодарность в статье равна, к примеру, двум дополнительным дням отпуска, но это уже зависит, где имярек работает)

Но как быть, когда тебе помог некий "холодильник.2003" (я утрирую), и он/она не выходит на связь, а завтра мне сдавать статью?

Comment: см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7

Comment: Если статья цитирует материал с SO или является от него "производным произведением", вы обязаны ссылаться с указанием имени автора. Если нет, то вы можете делать что угодно.

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to cite an answer in StackExchange?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/84965/445)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight статья не цитирует и не является, но автор помог ускорить получение результатов, которые будут описаны в статье. Может, я и не обязан в этом случае ссылаться, но мне совесть не позволит не сказать спасибо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Если время поджимает, можно приложить **сокращённую ссылку на профиль**. Она однозначно идентифицирует того, кто вам дал ответ, не требуя его вмешательства или раскрытия им какой-либо непубличной информации.

Выглядеть это может, к примеру, так:

> Благодарим участника сообщества "Stack Overflow на русском" с псевдонимом "холодильник 2003" (`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/123456/`) за ...

Скажем, вот как можно сократить ссылку вашего профиля:

- полная ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/242027/viktor-tomilov
- обезличенная: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/242027/ (имени больше нет)
- сокращённая: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/242027/ (`users`->`u`, спасибо [mymedia](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/183314/mymedia))
- даже конечную косую черту можно убрать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/242027

Видите? Работают одинаково. И в обозримом будущем, скорее всего, продолжат работать.

В печатаемых материалах длинные ссылки сильно мешают читать. А URL-экранирование кириллицы выдаёт по три символа на каждый кириллический. Выглядит кошмарно.

Comment: Гм... в научной статье, в журнале с огромным импакт-фактором - "Холодильник.2003" :D Это я так, мысленно примеряю клизму :) А вот обезличенная ссылка  мне более нравится.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov я какое-то время был под именем "Кнопкатык". Хорошая доза самоиронии полезна для здоровья :)

Comment: можно ссылки ещё больше сократить, заменив users на просто букву u

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, ну так ник-то всё равно надо указать кроме ссылки? Или ты хочешь просто в список источников её поместить без упоминания человека?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно извернуться, не указывая имени, сослаться на список на нашем оф.сайте, где потом, если достучусь до человека, уже указать его реальное имя и фамилию

Comment: "Видите? Работают одинаково." Ф. Фокус)